# Tkinter: How to pass arguments from Entry widgets to function?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have created two `Entry` widgets called `name_entry` and `passwd_entry`. After the user enters his name and password, the program should subsequently list it if the user clicks on the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button.

Unfortunately this is not working. I'm trying to write it within a class and to pass it as an argument to my submit function.

I receive this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: submit() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'var_name' and 'var_passwd'
```

Code:

```
#/usr/bin/python3.7
from tkinter import *

class Window (Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        var_name = StringVar()
        var_passwd = StringVar()

        name = Label(self, text="Name: ")
        name.place(x = 0, y = 0)
        name_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = var_name)
        name_entry.place(x = 90, y =0)

        passwd = Label(self, text="Password: ")
        passwd.place(x = 0, y = 90)
        passwd_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = var_passwd)
        passwd_entry.place(x = 90, y = 90)

        Knop1 = Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.submit)
        Knop1.place(x = 180, y=180)

    def submit (self, var_name, var_passwd):
        naam = var_name.get()
        var_passwd = var_passwd.get()
        print("The name is: ", naam)
        print("The password is: ", var_passwd)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
app = Window(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Can anyone help me? I'm also looking for a good Tkinter tutorial where OOP is being used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter binding a function with arguments to a widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299955/tkinter-binding-a-function-with-arguments-to-a-widget)

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.3.5. Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) and [how-would-i-access-variables-from-one-class-to-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993795)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't passed the variables to the submit function button. For simple cases like this, you can use a lambda expression as a link between Tkinter and the callback function, otherwise Python will call the callback function before creating the widget: https://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm

```
from tkinter import *

class Window (Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        var_name = StringVar()
        var_passwd = StringVar()

        name = Label(self, text="Name: ")
        name.place(x = 0, y = 0)
        name_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = var_name)
        name_entry.place(x = 90, y =0)

        passwd = Label(self, text="Password: ")
        passwd.place(x = 0, y = 90)
        passwd_entry = Entry(root, textvariable =var_passwd)
        passwd_entry.place(x = 90, y = 90)

        # Changed this line
        Knop1 = Button(self, text="Submit", command=lambda: self.submit(var_name, var_passwd))
        Knop1.place(x = 180, y=180)

    def submit (self, var_name, var_passwd):
        naam = var_name.get()
        var_passwd = var_passwd.get()
        print("The name is: ", naam)
        print("The password is: ", var_passwd)

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
app = Window(root)
app.mainloop()
```

To address your question about OOP with tkinter, this question has some good advice: [Best way to structure a tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule it's best of the `command` of a button calls a function that accepts no arguments. Since you've made a special-purpose function that always operates on the same variables, you can have the directly access the variables.

First, make the variables an attribute of the class:

```
def init_window(self):
    ...
    self.var_name = StringVar()
    self.var_passwd = StringVar()
    ..
```

Then, define your function to access those variables:

```
def submit (self):
    naam = self.var_name.get()
    var_passwd = self.var_passwd.get()
    ...
```

And finally, modify how your button calls this function:

```
Knop1 = Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.submit)
```

---

Note: if you're not using the special properties of a tkinter variable (such as the trace mechanism), you don't need to use `StringVar` at all.

Example:

```
def init_window(self):
    ...
    self.name_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = var_name)
    self.passwd_entry = Entry(root, textvariable =var_passwd)
    ...

def submit (self):
    naam = self.name_entry.get()
    var_passwd = self.passwd_entry.get()
    ...
```