# Tkinter Leave event firing only on program startup?

Tags: button, tkinter, bind, mouseleave

I'm trying to place a small label hinting the user the keyboard shortcut bound to it, which works fine.

[image]

The problem arises when I'm leaving the button. The label disappears, but not quite. If I try to click the button in the area the label "used" to be, it won't fire, indicating that's it's somehow still there. So I thought maybe buttons have a Leave event already built in that raises them to the top level. I decided to try and override that, and basically tell the button go (or better yet, just stay) below the key-hint label `hit_button.bind("<Leave>", hit_button.lower(hit_button_keyhint)`, to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

```
                                       fg=hit_button['fg'])
    hit_button_keyhint.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.85, anchor='center')
    hit_button.bind("<Leave>", hit_button.lower(hit_button_keyhint))
```

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention, using `print("left")` I realized the event only triggered once on the game startup, but never again. Why would it trigger before I even entered the button with the cursor?

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function to the binding, Here you execute a function. (`hit_button.lower(hit_button_keyhint)`)

To do so, you should use a lambda.

You can get some clarifications here:
[Tkinter binding a function with arguments to a widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299955/tkinter-binding-a-function-with-arguments-to-a-widget)

But this should work:

```
hit_button.bind("<Leave>",lambda event, k=hit_button_keyhint:hit_button.lower(k)
```