# TypeError: action() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, class, tkinter, combobox

I used to work with this way of coding and it worked fine, but after going back to it a few weeks later, it does not anymore. I simplidied my code so it is easy to type here.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class wind(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        # id shutter
        self.SOURCE_SHUTTER = "/dev/ttyUSB0"

        # menu deroulant
        self.listeFlux = ["/dev/ttyUSB0", "/dev/ttyUSB1", "/dev/ttyUSB2", "/dev/ttyUSB3"]
        self.listeCombo = ttk.Combobox(self, values=self.listeFlux)
        self.listeCombo.current(0)
        self.listeCombo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.action)
        self.listeCombo.pack(side="top")
        
     def action(self):
        self.SOURCE_SHUTTER = self.listeCombo.get()
        print(self.SOURCE_SHUTTER)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = wind()
    win.geometry("800x600")
    win.mainloop()
```

This code gives me the error : TypeError: action() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.
Does someone know why ? I have seen people make this mistake but their error was that a parameter was missing "self" somewhere in their code, which I don't think I am forgetting here.

Thanks a lot for your help.
Valentin

I tried looking in another topic that had the same problem but mine seems different here.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299955/tkinter-binding-a-function-with-arguments-to-a-widget) help at all?

Comment: Yes it did work in the end with a bit of manipulation but it is not convenient at all, the solution with *args provided below worked in a better way. Thanks anyways !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event bindings in tkinter will inherently pass an `event` parameter to the bound function, so you'll need deal with it one way or another

###### Option 1

Add an `_event` parameter to the `action` method.

The leading underscore `_` is convention to let people know that the value is unused by the function, and `event` is the conventional name for the event argument taken by event-driven functions in tkinter. The default value of `None` isn't strictly necessary, but it's good practice.

```
def action(self, _event=None):
    self.SOURCE_SHUTTER = self.listeCombo.get()
    print(self.SOURCE_SHUTTER)
```

###### Option 2

Use `*_args` in your method definition to allow it to accept any number of arguments (as suggested in @3ddavies' answer!). Again, the `_` is convention for unused values, and `args` is convention for this type of parameter. As has been mentioned, the caveat here is that now your `action` method will accept any number of arguments - this is unlikely to be an issue in this particular case, but keep it in mind!

```
def action(self, *_args):
    self.SOURCE_SHUTTER = self.listeCombo.get()
    print(self.SOURCE_SHUTTER)
```

###### Option 3

Use a lambda to absorb the event and call `action` as an anonymous function

```
def __init__(self):
    ...  # code omitted for brevity
    self.listeCombo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda _event: self.action)
    ...

def action(self):  # NOTE: the 'event' parameter is no longer required here
    self.SOURCE_SHUTTER = self.listeCombo.get()
    print(self.SOURCE_SHUTTER)
```

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer, this makes everything clearer now !

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty fix would be to change the definition of `action` to:

```
def action(self, *args):
```

The underlying issue here is that `<<ComboboxSelected>>` seems to return a tuple, so when the event is triggered, both the `self` object and the tuple are being passed to the `action` function, which is causing the error.

The above solution is a "dirty fix" because it will allow the function to take any number of arguments greater than one.

Comment: This solution works fine, I see what you mean by "dirty fix" but thanks, it helped more than fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it works @Valentin. If this is the solution you intend to go with, please mark it as the accepted answer.