# Applying function to iterable?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I just wrote this function:

```
def _apply(mols, fn, *args, **kwargs):
    return [fn(m, *args, **kwargs) for m in mols if m ]
```

And I started thinking:

1. Can this be rewritten using `map`?
2. Is this already implemented in somewhere in python?

As far as I know, `map` can't pass arguments to the function, on the other hand, it may be somehow optimized and using some partial binding or lambdas I can reimplement it using `map`. Would that be beneficial?

Comment: Somehow can you try to describe what the code is intended to do?

Comment: @PauloBu - first of all, I changed the example code, previous one was just bad. What it does (or what my intention is), it applies function with args and kwargs to every item of itarable.

Comment: Note that `map` is fast only if used with built-in functions, so better use a LC.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Even `def` functions would be faster, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye I don't think so, the only difference is that the expression with `lambda` will have to do an additional step of compiling the `lambda` to a code object first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
from functools import partial

clean = partial(filter, None)

def _apply(mols, fn, *args, **kwargs):
    f = partial(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    return map(f, clean(mols))

def foo(m, a, b, c=123):
    return [m, a, b, c]

print _apply([11,22,'',33], foo, 'aa', 'bb', c=475)
```

(in python2, consider `itertools.imap/ifilter` instead of `map/filter` to avoid temporary lists).

The above illustrates "partial application", even more elegant would be currying, i.e. a function that returns a partially applied version of itself when called with less arguments than expected. Python doesn't have currying built-in, but it's easy to implement as a decorator (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9458386/989121):

```
@curry
def join_three(a,b,c):
    return '%s-%s-%s' % (a,b,c)

mols = [11,22,33]
print map(join_three('aa', 'bb'), mols)
# prints ['aa-bb-11', 'aa-bb-22', 'aa-bb-33']
```

That said, functional style is frowned upon in python, in most cases, comprehensions and generators are more "pythonic".

Comment: Yes, but is it any better then my solution?

Comment: Or simply `return map(partial(fn, *args, **kwargs), mols)`?

Comment: And there is a name for this technique, its called Function Currying :)

Comment: @thefourtheye: it's "partial application", not "currying". Similar yet different things.

Comment: @thefourtheye: I added an example to the post.

Answer (score 2):

Although I think what you currently have is quite pretty, something like this might work:

```
map(lambda m: fn(m, *args, **kwargs), filter(None, mols))
```

Filters out all elements from `mols` which evaluate to `False`, and then applies the function `fn` to these elements.

Time complexity for the algorithm is `O(n)`.

If your `mols` is really large you might want to use `itertools`:

```
from itertools import imap, ifilter

list(imap(lambda m: fn(m, *args, **kwargs), ifilter(None, mols)))
```

Comment: The same comment here - is there any benefit instead of using your solution versus mine?

Comment: @mnowotka I doubt it. Using itertools might be beneficial speed wise if you've got a huge list of things to process. Your version is good as it is.