# vectorized implementation of list sliding in numpy

Tags: python, loops, numpy, vectorization

from given numpy array [1,2,3,4] and window wz=2 (two elements before and two elements after every element) I have to get pairs *(central el, el from window)*. Pairs with unexisting elements could be skipped or substituted by zero. So on this example I have to get this:

```
[[1., 0.]
 [2., 1.]
 [3., 2.]
 [4., 3.]
 [1., 2.]
 [2., 3.]
 [3., 4.]
 [4., 0.]
 [1., 0.]
 [2., 0.]
 [3., 1.]
 [4., 2.]
 [1., 3.]
 [2., 4.]
 [3., 0.]
 [4., 0.]]
```

My implementation is extremely unefficient and looks like:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
l = x.shape[0]
for i in range(1, m):
    init = np.empty((x.shape[0]*2,2))
    init[:,0] = np.append(x, x)
    init[:l,1] = np.pad(x, (i,0), mode='constant')[:l]
    init[-l:,1] = np.pad(x, (0,i), mode='constant')[-l:]
    corpus.extend(init)
```

Could someone help with much more efficient solution?
On another simple test data and variants I've implemented I've got:

```
285 µs ± 19.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
379 µs ± 7.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `x` is some data, like words or random values and we need to recombine it we could use [reindexing mechanism](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html) in `numpy`.

**Substituted by zero version**

```py
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
wz = 2
zero = 0
```

Lets build indexing matrix.

```py
ri = np.arange(-wz,wz+1)+np.arange(x.shape[0]).reshape(-1,1)
print(ri)
```

*Output:*

```py
  [[-2, -1,  0,  1,  2],
   [-1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
   [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
   [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5]
```

Now if we add zero to `x` as last element we can replace wrong indexes with it index.

```py
np.place(ri,(ri<0)|(ri>x.shape[0]),x.shape[0]) #replace wrong indexes
np.vstack((
    np.hstack((x,[zero]))[ri].reshape(1,-1),#extending x with zero and reindexing 
    np.tile(x,2*wz+1)) #repeating basic `x` to each window position
    )#.T #uncomment .T to make it vertical
```

Output:

```py
 ([[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0],
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

---

**Skipped version**

The same idea, but in a slightly different order: produce a complete indexing matrix `[window_index,x_index]` then exclude the wrong pairs, and finally re-indexing 'x'.

```py
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
wz = 2
ri = np.vstack((
    (np.arange(-wz,wz+1)+np.arange(x.shape[0]).reshape(-1,1)).ravel(),#same index matrix flaten 
    np.tile(np.arange(x.shape[0]),2*wz+1) #repeating `x` indexes to each window position
    )) 
x[ri[:,(ri[0]>=0)&(ri[0]<x.shape[0])]]#.T #uncomment .T to make it vertical
```

Output:

```py
 [[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4],
  [3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2]]
```

---

**Update 1** (error fix) 
exclude zero from window to avoid pair duplication.

```py
x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
wz = 2
ri = np.vstack(((
        np.hstack(( np.arange(-wz,0), #remove zero from window
                    np.arange(1,wz+1)))+
        np.arange(x.shape[0]).reshape(-1,1)).ravel(), #same index matrix flaten 
    np.tile(np.arange(x.shape[0]),2*wz) #repeating `x` indexes to each window position
    )) 
x[ri[:,(ri[0]>=0)&(ri[0]<x.shape[0])]]#.T #uncomment .T to make it vertical
```

Output:

```py
  [[2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3],
   [3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]]
```

---

Check documentation on used functions [np.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html),  [np.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), [np.place](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html), [np.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html),  [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html).

Comment: Ilia, thanks, your solution is exactly the one I've looked for, which accept random input parameters for initial array and window size. However the output wasn't the same then my. I found the issue in indexing matrix - the initial array used to construct it should not contain zeros [-2 -1 2 1 ] instead of [-2 -1 0 1 2 ]

Comment: @IvanTelnov Did you run performance tests? What is new benchmark?

Comment: so my previous (different to one i've gave in question) solution vs one according your approach:304 µs ± 8.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each) VS
84.2 µs ± 748 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

Comment: Why do optimize so small timing? Maybe we should optimaze bigger scope to have valuable improvement?

Comment: Every input array represents the indexes of words in it. So the size of loop could not be larger then just amount of words in very big sentence.

Comment: And unfortunately I cant concatenate all sentences in one big array and then use slide-window function in it, cos window shouldn't take words from different sentences, so in both cases I iterate through given arrays (sentences) and them use sliding-window function. That's why testing in on really big array doesn't make a sense for me. However, the difference of performance really grows with amount of sentences, from 2 times better (as I've shown) to 6 times, but it's rather cumulative performance. Now I think how to change my algorithm to use prospective performance of current solution better

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Numpythonic approach:

```
In [23]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
In [24]: arr = np.hstack((a-1, a+1, a - 2, a+ 2))
In [25]: mask = ~np.in1d(arr, a)
In [26]: arr[mask] = 0
In [27]: np.column_stack((np.tile(a, 4), arr))
Out[27]: 
array([ [1, 0],
        [2, 1],
        [3, 2],
        [4, 3],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 4],
        [4, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [2, 0],
        [3, 1],
        [4, 2],
        [1, 3],
        [2, 4],
        [3, 0],
        [4, 0]])
```

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question but what does the `~` do here?

Comment: @erocoar It acts like a logical_not, converts True to False and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The numpy approach is favorable, but here is a functional approach for those interested:

**Given**

```
import functools as ft


# Helper function
def curry(f):
    @ft.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(arg):
        try:
            return f(arg)
        except TypeError:
            return curry(ft.wraps(f)(ft.partial(f, arg)))
    return wrapped
```

**Code**

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
c = curry(lambda x, y: x + y)
funcs = [c(-1), c(1), c(-2), c(2)]
set_ = set(lst)


[[x, 0] if fn(x) not in set_ else [x, fn(x)] for fn in funcs for x in lst]
```

Output

```
[[1, 0],
 [2, 1],
 [3, 2],
 [4, 3],
 [1, 2],
 [2, 3],
 [3, 4],
 [4, 0],
 [1, 0],
 [2, 0],
 [3, 1],
 [4, 2],
 [1, 3],
 [2, 4],
 [3, 0],
 [4, 0]]
```

---

**Details**

In the double `for` loops of the list comprehension, a list of [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) functions is iterated, and each function is applied to every element of the primary list (`lst`). Currying allows you to compute new values by passing in some argument (e.g. `1, -1, -2, 2`) and later passing in an element from the primary list.

Tuples are created, e.g *(primary element, computed element)*.  The conditional part of the list comprehension, substitutes `0` for computed elements not found in primary list.

See also this [implementation of the `curry` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30714089/4531270).