# How to compose (combine) several function calls with arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, function-declaration

My full question sound this way: How to compose (combine) several function calls with arguments without using partial.

Right now current code below works fine, but I need to call partial every time any additional argument is provided:

```py
    from functools import partial

    def pipe(data, *funcs):
        for func in funcs:
            data = func(data)
        return data

    def mult(data, amount=5, bias=2):
        return data*amount + bias

    def divide(data, amount, bias=1):
        return data/amount + bias

    result = pipe(5,
                    mult, 
                    partial(divide, amount=10)
                 )
    print(result)
    # 3.7
```

But I would like to partial to be called inside of pipe function. So calling should start looking this way:

```py
    result = pipe(5,
                     mult, 
                     divide(amount=10)
                 )
```

Comment: Consider https://stackoverflow.com/q/9458271/476.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation that may help you. It's a decorator to use on functions so that you can create `partial` function by calling the function itself, rather than `partial(func, ...)`:

```
from functools import partial, wraps

def make_partial(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return partial(func, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

With any function that you want your behaviour with, decorate it like so:

```
@make_partial
def divide(data, amount, bias=1):
    return data/amount + bias
```

Now you can call `pipe` as you describe as calling `divide(amount=10)` now returns a partial too.

```
result = pipe(5, mult, divide(amount=10))
```

It would be difficult to make the `partial` call within `pipe` as you would somehow need to pass in the desired function and its default arguments without calling it. This method tries to eliminate this and keep your existing functions clean.

---

The only other way I can suggest is that you pass a list of functions, a list of lists of partial args and a list of dicts of keyword arguments. Your function signature would be `pipe(data, funcs, args, kwargs)`.

```
def pipe(data, funcs, args, kwargs):
    for func, arg_list, kwarg_list in zip(funcs, args, kwargs):
        data = partial(func, *arg_list, **kwarg_list)(data)
    return data
```

To call `pipe`, it gets a bit more complicated:

```
result = pipe(
    5,
    [mult, divide],
    [[], []],
    [{}, {'amount': 10}]
)
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but I believe there is must be a way, maybe without wraping all functions https://albumentations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html

Comment: Please see my edit. You could easily change this so you input the data for the functions in different formats, but this seems clear enough.