# Performant way to partially apply in Python?

Tags: python, lambda, partial-application

I am looking for a way to partially apply functions in python that is simple to understand, readable, resusable and as little error prone to coder mistakes as possible. Most of all I want the style to be as performant as possible - less frames on the stack is nice, and less memory footprint for the partially applied functions is also desirable. I have considered 4 styles and written examples below:

```py
import functools

def multiplier(m):
    def inner(x):
        return m * x

    return inner

def divide(n,d):
    return n/d

def divider(d):
    return functools.partial(divide,d=d)

times2 = multiplier(2)
print(times2(3))  # 6

by2 = divider(2)
print(by2(6)) # 3.0

by3 = functools.partial(divide,d=3)
print(by3(9)) # 3.0

by4 = lambda n: divide(n,4)
print(by4(12)) # 3.0
```

My analysis of them are:

**`times2`** is a nested thing. I guess python makes a closure with the `m` bound, and everything is nice. The code is readable (I think) and simple to understand. No external libraries. This is the style I use today.

**`by2`** has an explicit named function which makes it simple for the user. It uses functools, so it gives you extra imports. I like this style to some extent since it is transparent, and give me the option to use `divide` in *other* ways if I want to. Contrast this with `inner` which is not reachable.

**`by3`** is like `by2`, but forces the reader of the code to be comfortable with `functools.partial` since they have it right in the face. what I like less is that PyCharm cant give my tooltips with what the arguments to `functools.partial` should be, since they are effectively arguments to `by3`. I have to know the signature of `divide` myself everytime I define some new partial application.

**`by4`** is simple to type, since I can get autocompletion. It needs no import of `functools`. I think it looks non-pythonic though. Also, I always feel uncomfortable about scoping of variables / closures with lambdas work in python. Never sure how that behaves....

**What is the logical difference between the styles and how does that affect memory and CPU?**

Comment: This is fairly broad. I don't think there is any consensus about this, so use what feels right. In terms of functionality, they are basically equivalent. In terms of speed, you can check it yourself with `timeit` (don't think there would be a significant difference)

Comment: @JohnColeman I understand that. I'll rewrite to narrow it down !

Comment: The comparisons might be more directly meaningful if you have exactly the same function (say the one that sends x to 2x) defined in four different ways rather than 4 different functions defined in 4 different ways.

Comment: Might also be interesting: [Currying decorator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9458271/1639625)

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks for pointing out the imporance of doing that same maths in every case to making it comparable. When I started a rewrite of the question I realized your answer below actually answers my question well. Also - It gave me the tools I needed to settle the question myself on my machine and with the in-context functions. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first way seems to be the most efficient. I tweaked your code so that all 4 functions compute exactly the same mathematical function:

```
import functools,timeit

def multiplier(m):
    def inner(x):
        return m * x

    return inner

def mult(x,m):
    return m*x

def multer(m):
    return functools.partial(mult,m=m)

f1 = multiplier(2)
f2 = multer(2)
f3 = functools.partial(mult,m=2)
f4 = lambda x: mult(x,2)

print(timeit.timeit('f1(10)',setup = 'from __main__ import f1'))
print(timeit.timeit('f2(10)',setup = 'from __main__ import f2'))
print(timeit.timeit('f3(10)',setup = 'from __main__ import f3'))
print(timeit.timeit('f4(10)',setup = 'from __main__ import f4'))
```

Typical output (on my machine):

```
0.08207898699999999
0.19439769299999998
0.20093803199999993
0.1442435820000001
```

The two `functools.partial` approaches are identical (since one of them is just a wrapper for the other), the first is twice as fast, and the last is somewhere in between (but closer to the first). There is a clear overhead in using `functools` over a straightforward closure. Since the closure approach is arguably more readable as well (and more flexible than the lambda which doesn't extend well to more complicated functions) I would just go with it.

Answer (score 3):

Technically you're missing one other option as [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.mul) does the same thing you're looking to do and you can just use `functools.partial` on it to get a default first argument without having to reinvent the wheel.

Not only is it the fastest option it also uses the least space compared to a custom function or a lambda statement. The fact that it's a `partial` is why it uses the same space as the others and I think that's the best route here.

```
from timeit import timeit
from functools import partial
from sys import getsizeof
from operator import mul

def multiplier(m):
    def inner(x):
        return m * x
    return inner

def mult(x,m):
    return m*x

def multer(m):
    return partial(mult,m=m)

f1 = multiplier(2)
f2 = multer(2)
f3 = partial(mult,m=2)
f4 = lambda n: mult(n,2)
f5 = partial(mul, 2)
from_main = 'from __main__ import {}'.format

print(timeit('f1(10)', from_main('f1')), getsizeof(f1))
print(timeit('f2(10)', from_main('f2')), getsizeof(f2))
print(timeit('f3(10)', from_main('f3')), getsizeof(f3))
print(timeit('f4(10)', from_main('f4')), getsizeof(f4))
print(timeit('f5(10)', from_main('f5')), getsizeof(f5))
```

Output

```
0.5278953390006791 144
1.0804575479996856 96
1.0762036349988193 96
0.9348237040030654 144
0.3904160970050725 96
```

This should answer your question as far as memory usage and speed.

Comment: Not sure I understand your answer. You are saying that you can use `operator.mul`, which is somewhat besides the point, as the multiplication-function is probably just a simple example for testing and not what OP really would be using. Then you say that for `operator.mul`, `partial` is best, and thus `partial` _is_ best (in all cases?) even though it is slower than a `def` function?

Comment: Where did I say for all cases? In this case using `partial` and `operator.mul` is the fastest as all OP seems to be trying to do is add a default arg to another but not the most estensible as partial cannot accept positional arguments. It is although an option that can be considered. I am only stating that `operator.mul` IS another option and is faster than making your own.