# How can I get informations about the parameters on a function or closure in Rust?

Tags: function, rust, parameters, arguments

Like `formals (func)` in R or `func.__code__.co_argcount` in Python. The number of a function's parameter could be get by them in their language, but I did not find a way to get that at rust yet.

Those are meta information about a function I guess, such as types about parameters or number of parameters. Is there any syntax or macro to get that ?

Comment: Rust doesn't have introspection.

Comment: This is likely a XY-Problem, what are you trying to do with the information? Why isn't looking at the signature enough?

Comment: I want to write a function `curry` in rust like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458271/currying-decorator-in-python/78025654#78025654 . I've already have a `fixedpoint` function.

Comment: You'd want to write a (probably procedual) macro `curry` that takes your function definition as input for that. I don't think a function `curry` is possible in Rust.

Comment: Thanks the hint, but I've already have a macro curry ... now I just want to try another way ...

Comment: Is there some way to make a param match test ? Such as `let f = |(u8, (u8, &str))| {...}` then `match_test (f, (2, (3, "4")))`, this is also a way to slove my plight.

Comment: Proc macro is probably the way to go. But why do you want it anyway? If you want to use Rust as a purely functional language, then just use Haskell instead. What code this allows you to write, which was earlier *impossible*?

Comment: Just a challenge ... now I slove this plight by give a argslength it should be, so I don't need to get the number of a function's parameters anymore. Well, thanks your advice also.