# thread starts running before calling Thread.start

Tags: python, multithreading, callback, python-multithreading

```
t1=threading.Thread(target=self.read())
print("something")
t2=threading.Thread(target=self.runChecks(), args=(self,))
```

`self.read` runs indefinitely, so the program won't ever reach the `print` line. How is this possible without calling `t1.start()`? (Even if I call that, it should start running and go on to the next line, shouldn't it?)

---

<sub>See also: [What does it mean when the parentheses are omitted from a function call (supposing no arguments are necessary)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785933/) for a deeper understanding of the bug, and [Python Argument Binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277922) for a more general solution.</sub>

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Because of the trailing `()` on the `target=self.read()`, you're running `self.read` in the wrong thread, the *current* thread — not the new thread you're creating — and passing the *return value* of the `self.read` call as the `target` argument of `Thread`. `Thread` expects to be passed a function to call, so just remove the parentheses and remember to start the thread:

```
t1=threading.Thread(target=self.read)
t1.start()
print("something")
```

For targets that need arguments, you can use the `args` and `kwargs` arguments to `threading.Thread`, or you can use a lambda. For example, to run `f(a, b, x=c)` in a thread, you could use

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(a, b), kwargs={'x': c})
```

or

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: f(a, b, x=c))
```

though watch out if you pick the lambda - the lambda will look up `f`, `a`, `b`, and `c` at time of use, not when the `lambda` is defined, so you may get unexpected results if you reassign any of those variables before the thread is scheduled (which could take arbitrarily long, even if you call `start` immediately).

Comment: Jeez, wish all tuotrials would mention this!
https://www.quantstart.com/articles/parallelising-python-with-threading-and-multiprocessing/

Comment: @TCSGrad yep, the code there is simply broken. I, too, wish the world wasn't drowning in sucky tutorials, but that's part of the price we pay for freedom.