# How to run infinite loops within threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I've looked everywhere and it *seems* like the threads I write should work. I've checked many other threads about it and tutorials. I can't seem to run infinite loops in threads. Despite what I do, only the first thread works/prints.

Here is the code for just methods.

```py
import threading


def thread1():
      while True:
            print("abc")
def thread2():
      while True:
            print ("123")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread1())
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=thread2())

    t1.start
    t2.start

    t1.join
    t2.join
```

Removing the prentheses at the end of calling the functions with `target=`causes nothing to print so I keep that in there.

Here is the class/object version.

```py
from threading import Thread
class Thread1(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start

    def run():
        while True:
            print ("abc")

class Thread2(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start

    def run():
        while True:
            print ("123")

Thread1.run()
Thread2.run()
```

both never get to printing `123` and I can't figure out why. It looks like infinite loops shouldn't be an issue because they are being run in parallel. I tried `time.sleep` (bc maybe the GIL stopped it idk) so thread2 could run while thread1 was idle. Didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [thread starts running before calling Thread.start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792629/thread-starts-running-before-calling-thread-start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread1)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=thread2)

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Pass the function, not the result of calling the function, to `threading.Thread` as its `target`.

For the section example. Don't call `run`. Call `start`. After creating an instance.

```
from threading import Thread
class Thread1(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True

    def run():
        while True:
            print ("abc")

class Thread2(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True

    def run():
        while True:
            print ("123")

Thread1().start()
Thread2().start()
```

Comment: A duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792629/thread-starts-running-before-calling-thread-start

Answer (score 0):

Your parentheses are in the wrong places in the first version.

As currently written, you are passing the result of calling `thread1` when creating `t1`; since that call never returns, you never actually create a thread.  So you need to remove those parentheses.

But you *don't* include the parentheses where you are trying to call the `start` and `join` methods, so the threads never actually got started even when you didn't use the extra parentheses when creating the threads.