# Python multiprocessing not working when time.sleep is used

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have one function which will take different inputs and I want that function to run parallely. Below is what I tried , but it's not working due to time.sleep I think.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep
import time

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)
    time.sleep(10)

l1 = Queue()
a = Process(target=f('Tom'))
a.start()

l2 = Queue()
b = Process(target=f("Stock"))
b.start()

print (l1.get())
print (l2.get())
```

I want the function to run parallely. Currently the function waits for 10 seconds before it goes to the second execution.

Comment: You are *calling the function* then passing the result to `Process`, in this case, `None`, right here: `a = Process(target=f('Tom'))` [Look at the multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process), what does it say about the value you are supposed to pass to `target`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [thread starts running before calling Thread.start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792629/thread-starts-running-before-calling-thread-start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comment posted by @juanpa.arrivillaga. Just specify as the *target* argument of the `Process` constructor the *name* of the function; do not call the function. The arguments to your *target* are specified separately as the *args* argument, either as a `tuple` or a `list`.

Also, since `f` is not returning a useful value, there is no reason to have `Queue` instances for the results. In any case, you are not passing the `Queue` instances to `f` and nothing is being `put` to the queue so I can't understand why you would be attempting to issue calls to `get` against these `Queue` instances; these calls will hang forever. The argument you *do* need to be passing to `f` is the *name*, as follows:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
#from time import sleep
import time

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)
    time.sleep(10)

start_time = time.time()

a = Process(target=f, args=('Tom',))
a.start()

b = Process(target=f, args=("Stock",))
b.start()

# Wait for processes to complete
a.join()
b.join()

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print(elapsed_time)
```

Prints:

```
hello Tom
hello Stock
10.212252855300903
```

If you were running this on a platform such as Windows, then you would need to place the process-creating code in a special block as follows;

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
#from time import sleep
import time

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)
    time.sleep(10)

# Required on platforms that create processes with the "spawn" method:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()

    a = Process(target=f, args=('Tom',))
    a.start()

    b = Process(target=f, args=("Stock",))
    b.start()

    # Wait for processes to complete
    a.join()
    b.join()

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(elapsed_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Pool` and `starmap`:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def f(name, place):
    print('hello', name, place)
    time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [('Louis', 'val1'), ('Paul', 'val2'), ('Alexandre', 'val3'),
            ('John', 'val4'), ('Tom', 'val5'), ('Bob', 'val6')]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as pool:
        pool.starmap(f, data)
```

Read carefully the [multiprocessing guidlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods)

> *Safe importing of main module*
>
> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process).

Comment: I think more than anything, `__main__` is the important part.

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks for the reply . Assuming the function takes 2 input arguments , `def f(name , place )` . In this scenario how can we implement the multiprocessing.

Comment: This answer just seems to avoid the problem. The error made in the question code is an important one to understand. Merely showing how a *different* approach looks when done correctly doesn't seem to cover that.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi. I don't avoid the problem. The question is *I want the function to run parallely.*. Does my solution not answer to that?

Comment: @MeenakshisundaramRamanathan. I updated my question and replace `map` by `starmap`. I replace `names` by a list of tuples.

Comment: @Corralien The question doesn't ask anything in specific. What it does do is show an error from a small but severe misunderstanding. I think showing a different approach is fine, but doing so without any explanation on *what* the issue was or *why* the other code fixes it isn't helpful.