# Tkinter assign button command in a for loop with lambda

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a few `Button`s (with a `for` loop) like so:

```
def a(self, name):
    print(name)

users = {"Test": "127.0.0.0", "Test2": "128.0.0.0"}
row = 1
for name in users:
    user_button = Tkinter.Button(self.root, text=name,
                                 command=lambda: self.a(name))
    user_button.grid(row=row, column=0)
    row += 1
```

and for the buttons to each get their own parameter (Test getting `"Test"` and Test2 getting `"Test2"`), but when I press the buttons they both print `"Test2"` which means they are using the same function with the same parameter.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The problem is your `lambda` expression in the `for` loop. It is using the `name` variable, but the `name` variable gets reassigned each iteration of the `for` loop, so in the end, all of the buttons get the last value that `name` was assigned to in the for loop. To avoid this you can use default keyword parameters in your `lambda` expression like so:

```
user_button = Tkinter.Button(self.root, text=name,
                             command=lambda name=name: self.a(name))
```

This binds the current value of the `name` variable to the lambda's `name` keyword argument each time through the loop, producing the desired effect.

Comment: It is not a tkinter issue, it is an issue concerning nesting of functions, closures, etc. It as well exists in completely other contexts. Nevertheless +1, as it otherwise describes exactly what happens.

Comment: @glglgl You're 100% correct. Not the best choice of words on my part, will revise.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. This saved me from some more hours of search.

Comment: what if we want to execute multiple function? self.a and self.b

Comment: this worked for me, but I've noticed a lot of strange things like this with lambda. Is there a reason lambda is needed at all?

Comment: @1QuickQuestion please see [Python argument binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277922) and [Why is my Button's command executed immediately when I create the Button, and not when I click it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228).

Comment: thanks for this i was havving issues.  =).      btw  if you have multiple arguments you can do lambda parm1=parm1, parm2, parm2: my_function(parm1, parm2)