# Late binding closures in this code

Tags: python

I came across this code which is one of Python's gotchas:

```
def create_multipliers():
    return [lambda x : i * x for i in range(5)]
for multiplier in create_multipliers():
    print multiplier(2)
```

I read the solution [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures) but I am confused at some places. I have two questions:

1. Why is it printing `8,8,8,8,8` instead of `0,2,4,6,8`?
2. They come up with this solution

   ```
   def create_multipliers():
       return [lambda x, i=i : i * x for i in range(5)]
   ```

   What is `i=i` doing and why it used?

Comment: Your link is literally to `http://here`, which isn't terribly helpful.

Comment: @jonrsharpe its not duplicate sir , please don't mark it duplicate

Comment: 1. That link still wasn't right, but I fixed it. 2. Absolutely it's a duplicate. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/17677649/3001761. You are talking about the same behaviour and the existing answers explain everything.

Comment: If, having read all the answers on the two linked questions, you *still* have a question, please [edit] to make it clear what that question is and how the information you already have fails to answer it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i didn't understand that explanation please remove duplicate :/

Comment: @micro192 Edit your question with a more detailed explanation of what you don't understand.

Comment: No, that's not a good reason. What **precisely** do you still not understand? And if you can't understand the existing answers, why do you think another answer will help at all?