# Tkinter radio button dynamic grid

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tkinter, radio-button

I use the following code to create dynamic radio buttons grid:

```
for data in self.datatoparse:
    Label(self.topframe, text=data["column"]).grid(row=row, column=0)
    for k in range(0,columnscount):
        var = {"column":data["column"],"index":k}
        Radiobutton(self.topframe, text="", variable=data, value=var, command=lambda: self.test(row,var)).grid(row=row, column=k+1)
    row = row + 1
```

When I click on a radio button it does not update the elements inside self.datatoparse list.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is this your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677649/tkinter-assign-button-command-in-loop-with-lambda

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the problem of the lambda but the datatoparse list is not updated

Comment: Why do you think `dataoparse` should be updated? There's no code trying to update it. What does "update" even mean here?

Comment: The code iterates through "datatoparse" using "data" element. "data" is the variable linked to each row of radio buttons so whenever I click on a Radio button "data" should get the value of that radio

Comment: is `data` a `StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc. If not then it will no update automatically. Your `data` has some `data["column"]` so it seams it is some dictionary, not `StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc.