# Tkinter button arguments

Tags: python, tkinter

I've started learning python recently. I have little experience in gui and wanted to learn some more. With little research, I've found tkinter to make it real. As a project, decided to make the game mastermind.

What I'm doing is putting some rows with OptionMenu with the available colors. On the right I've put a confirm button, that has the command "validate" set. The thing is that I want to pass different values to each button (the frame and the row) with the following code, the problem I have is that it says that the row is always 9.

I've thought a possible solution, that is to reset at the end y=0 and every time I press the button add 1. But I think it should be simpler.

```
from tkinter import *

def selectedColor(var):
    print("Value is: " + var)

def validate(frame, row):
    # pass
    print("Frame: " + str(frame) + " row: " + str(row))
    rowToValidate = frame.nametowidget("." + str(row))
    for x in range(0,4):
        columnValue = frame.nametowidget("." + str(x) + str(row))
        print(columnValue)

master = Tk()

OPTIONS

 = [
    "RED",
    "BLUE",
    "YELLOW",
    "VIOLET",
    "ORANGE",
    "GREEN",
    "BROWN",
    "WHITE",
    "BLACK"
]

colorQuantity = 4
tries = 10
for y in range(0, tries):
    frame = Frame(master, name=str(y))
    isEnabled = "disabled" if y != 0 else "normal"
    for x in range(0,colorQuantity):
        variable = StringVar(frame, name=str(x)+str(y))
        variable.set("Choose color") # default value
        # print(str(variable))

        w = OptionMenu(frame, variable, *OPTIONS, command=selectedColor)        
        w.configure(state=isEnabled)
        w.pack(side=LEFT)
    confirmButton = Button(frame, text="Confirm", command= lambda: validate(frame, y+1))
    confirmButton.configure()
    confirmButton.pack(side=TOP)
    print(str(frame))
    frame.pack(side=TOP)


master.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have a problem  because of the `lambda` in a for loop (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture/2295372#2295372 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677649/tkinter-assign-button-command-in-loop-with-lambda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would save the OptionMenu variables in a list, to make it easier to retrieve their values. By using `partial` ([link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)) in the command option, you can make sure each row get the correct row number as input.

See the code below (I've also added a bit of formatting on the dropdowns):

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

def selectedColor(var):
    print("Value is: " + var)

def validate(args):
    frame = args[0]
    row = args[1]

    for x in range(0,4):
        print(rows[row][x].get())

master = Tk()

OPTIONS = [
    "RED",
    "BLUE",
    "YELLOW",
    "VIOLET",
    "ORANGE",
    "GREEN",
    "BROWN",
    "WHITE",
    "BLACK"
]

colorQuantity = 4
tries = 10
rows =[]
for y in range(0, tries):
    frame = Frame(master, name=str(y))
    isEnabled = "disabled" if y != 0 else "normal"
    row = []
    for x in range(0,colorQuantity):
        variable = StringVar(frame, name=str(x)+str(y))
        variable.set("Choose color") # default value
        # print(str(variable))
        row.append(variable)

        w = OptionMenu(frame, variable, *OPTIONS, command=selectedColor)  
        w.configure(width=len("Choose color"))      
        w.configure(state=isEnabled)
        w.pack(side=LEFT)
    rows.append(row)
    confirmButton = Button(frame, text="Confirm", command=partial(validate,(frame, y)))
    confirmButton.configure()
    confirmButton.pack(side=TOP)
    print(str(frame))
    frame.pack(side=TOP)


master.mainloop()
```