# Python 3 Tkinter bind event recognize which element

Tags: python, tkinter, hover, bind

I have two canvases (elements):

```
self.canvas1
self.canvas2
```

I want them to do `something()` when the mouse **hover** over the canvas.

So I hook it up using the `bind('<Enter>')`:

```
self.canvas1.bind('<Enter>', something)
self.canvas2.bind('<Enter>', something)
```

In the `something()` it will try to configure the canvas to red background color so:

```
def something(event):
    canvas.configure(background='red')
```

The tricky part is, how does the function `something` know which canvas it suppose to change its background color to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event object has a `widget` attribute, which refers to the widget that generated the event. You could use that.

```
event.widget.configure(background="red")
```

---

If, for whatever reason, you don't want to do this, you could create an anonymous function which keeps a closure of your widget variable, and then you can pass it as an argument to your function directly.

```
self.canvas1.bind('<Enter>', lambda event: something(self.canvas1))
#or possibly*
self.canvas1.bind('<Enter>', lambda event, canvas1=self.canvas1: something(canvas1))
```

You'd have to change your `something` function's parameters to `def something(widget):` in that case.

(*The `canvas1=self.canvas1` is only necessary if you're binding in a loop, as in [Tkinter assign button command in loop with lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17677649/953482))

Comment: The first solution `event.widget.configure(background="red")` is much better and is perfect for me. I just had to wait for the _accept answer cool down_