# Identify button when generated in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I am trying to program a minesweeper game on python using tkinter. I started off by creating a grid of buttons using a two dimensional list, and the generation of the button and everything works. The only issue I have is that I don't know how to determine which button in my grid is clicked. My goal is to be able to click on a button and through that I know the coordinates of that in my grid [row][col].

This is the code I have so far.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
from itertools import product

# Here, we are creating our class, Window, and inheriting from the Frame
# class. Frame is a class from the tkinter module. (see Lib/tkinter/__init__)
class Window(Frame):


    # Define settings upon initialization. Here you can specify
    def __init__(self, master=None):

        # parameters that you want to send through the Frame class. 
        Frame.__init__(self, master)   

        #reference to the master widget, which is the tk window                 
        self.master = master

        #with that, we want to then run init_window, which doesn't yet exist
        numRows = int(input("# of Rows: "))
        numCols = int(input("# of Cols: "))

        self.init_window(numRows, numCols)

    #Creation of init_window
    def init_window(self, rowNum, colNum):
        # print(x, y)
        # changing the title of our master widget      
        self.master.title("GUI")

        # allowing the widget to take the full space of the root window
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # creating a button instance
        #quitButton = Button(self, text="Exit",command=self.client_exit)

        # placing the button on my window
        #quitButton.place(x=0, y=0)
        but = []
        for row in range(0, rowNum):
            curRow = []
            for col in range(0, colNum):
                curRow.append(Button(self, bg="gray", width=2,height=1, command=lambda: self.open_button(row, col)))
                curRow[col].grid(row=row,column=col)
            but.append(curRow)

        #but[1][1].config(state="disabled")
        #but[1][1]["text"] = "3"
        #but[1][1]["bg"] = "white"

    def open_button(self, r, c):
        print(r, " : ", c)

# root window created. Here, that would be the only window, but
# you can later have windows within windows.
root = Tk()

root.geometry("600x600")

#creation of an instance
app = Window(root)

#mainloop 
root.mainloop()
```

Whenever I click on the grid, it gives me the very last button...
For example, a 9x9 grid always gives me "9 : 9" whenever I click any button.

Solutions welcomed! I want an easy way to get the coordinates without changing too much of the code (if possible).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `row` and `col` variables are assigned each value in the `range`s. At the end of the loop that generates the buttons, the values for those variables are left at the last values in the ranges, e.g. "9 : 9".

Try replacing the line

```
curRow.append(Button(self, bg="gray", width=2,height=1, command=lambda: self.open_button(row, col)))
```

with

```
curRow.append(Button(self, bg="gray", width=2,height=1, command=lambda rw=row, cl=col: self.open_button(rw, cl)))
```

This assigns the values of `row` and `col` at the time the button is created to the variables `rw` and `cl`, which remain the same for each button as the for-loop iterates.

See this link:
[Tkinter assign button command in loop with lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677649/tkinter-assign-button-command-in-loop-with-lambda)