# Creating Menu in for loop uses last index value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a `Menu` in Python 3.7 using Tkinter. When I create a menu with hard-coded values like:

```
obj_menu = Menu(textbox, tearoff=0)
obj_menu.add_command(label="a", command=lambda : foo("a", index))
index = index + 1
obj_menu.add_command(label="b", command=lambda : foo("b", index))
```

everything works fine. in my callback method **foo()** I get a and b correct values when select 1st and 2nd menu item respectively.

But when I create this menu in for loop, I always get **last char** in my callback method foo().

```
for idx, char in enumerate(alphabets):
    obj_menu.add_command(label=char, command=lambda : foo(char, idx))
```

I'm confused as why the method only gets value of last index no matter which menu index I select. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can still use `lambda` by forcing a closure. Read [Tkinter assign button command in loop with lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677649/tkinter-assign-button-command-in-loop-with-lambda)

Comment: Thanks @HenryYik that was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to create temporary variable in lambda and use them in method call.

```
for idx, char in enumerate(alphabets):
obj_menu.add_command(label=char, command=lambda c=char, i=idx : foo(c, i))
```

Thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17677768/970422

Answer (score 1):

If you did want to create a list of functions, rather than using `lambda` you could make use of Python's [`partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools#functools.partial) function from the `functools` library. For example:

```
for idx, char in enumerate(alphabets):
    obj_menu.add_command(label=char, command=partial(foo, char, idx))
```

The following shows the results of the two different approaches in a small test example:

```
from functools import partial

def foo(char, idx):
    print(char, idx)
    return idx

alphabets = "abc"

print("Using lambda")
funcs = []

for idx, char in enumerate(alphabets):
    funcs.append([char, lambda : foo(char, idx)])

for char, func in funcs:
    print(char, func())

print("\nUsing partial")
funcs = []

for idx, char in enumerate(alphabets):
    funcs.append([char, partial(foo, char, idx)])

for char, func in funcs:
    print(char, func())
```

This would display the following output:

```
Using lambda
a 2
a 2
b 2
b 2
c 2
c 2

Using partial
a 0
a 0
b 1
b 1
c 2
c 2
```

As can be seen, the first approach fails, resulting in the last `lambda` variant being used for all calls, whereas the `partial()` functions works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a lambda expression of that form, you are actually doing equivalent of something like this:

```
index = [whatever value]
def _implicit_func():
    return foo("a", index)
obj_menu.add_command(label="a", command=_implicit_func)
```

I hope that you can see that this `index` variable is also available outside of the function's scope. This means that you can edit this variable, and it will alter all future executions of said function.

If you are still confused, [here's a reference](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) on Python variables' scopes.

Comment: How can I create dynamic Menu in Python and have a callback for each row?