# Using For loop to call a function with a series of arguments

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to take this code:

```
buttons[0]=Button(boardFrame,text=' ', command=lambda: boardButtonClick(1))
buttons[0].grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='news',ipadx=10,ipady=10)

buttons[1]=Button(boardFrame,text=' ', command=lambda: boardButtonClick(2))
buttons[1].grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='news',ipadx=10,ipady=10)

buttons[2]=Button(boardFrame,text=' ', command=lambda: boardButtonClick(3))
buttons[2].grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='news',ipadx=10,ipady=10)

buttons[3]=Button(boardFrame,text=' ', command=lambda: boardButtonClick(4))
buttons[3].grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='news',ipadx=10,ipady=10)
....
```

and so on...

And to make it short using a for loop.
that's what I tried:

```
i=0
for j in range(0,3):
    for k in range(0,3):
        buttons[i]=Button(boardFrame,text=' ', command=lambda: boardButtonClick(i))
        buttons[i].grid(row=j,column=k,sticky='news',ipadx=10,ipady=10)
        i+=1
```

All the arguments works good, But there is a problem with the argument that sent to the function in this part: `command=lambda: boardButtonClick(i)`

Thanks.

Comment: And what is the problem with that? Are you getting an error? You have unexpected value? what value you get?

Comment: command=lambda: boardButtonClick(i+1)

Comment: There is one more step to be done: `command=lambda i=i+1: boardButtonClick(i)`. Read [Tkinter assign button command in loop with lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677649/tkinter-assign-button-command-in-loop-with-lambda).

Comment: @HenryYik that's was my problem! thank you. You can post it as answer.

Comment: No problem. You can upvote the answer linked in the question instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to your first code part, you are starting with

```
buttons[0]=Button(boardFrame,text=' ', command=lambda: boardButtonClick(1))
```

But in your loop, your are starting with i=0 and then :

```
buttons[i]=Button(boardFrame,text=' ', command=lambda: boardButtonClick(i))
```

This line will be the following :

```
buttons[0]=Button(boardFrame,text=' ', command=lambda: boardButtonClick(0))
```

If you want your first code part result, try this instead:

```
buttons[i]=Button(boardFrame,text=' ', command=lambda: boardButtonClick(i+1))
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I care the `i=0` and `i=1` issue in the `boardButtonClick()` function itself so this is not the problem.
The problem was that `boardButtonClick(i)` didn't send `i` to the function at all.
@HenryYik solved it with adding `command=lambda i=i+1: boardButtonClick(i)`