# creating multiple buttons with different names in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to create multiple buttons with different names (each new name is equal to the name of the previous button + the iterating value at that moment.) Please help me out, here is my code.

```
buttons = [0]*len(gg.allStudents)

for j in range(len(gg.allStudents)):
    buttons[j] = tk.Button(wind, text=gg.allStudents[j].name, height = 2, width = 20, command=lambda: plotMarks(j))
    buttons[j].pack()
```

The looping conditions that I have used our correct. The only help I need is to find a way to store each new button with a new name into the 'buttons' list.

Comment: The buttons don't need names. You can reference them via the `buttons` array. Why do you think they need names?

Comment: What I intend to do is, when the user clicks on any button, a corresponding plot should pop up. Since I didn't name the buttons, the same 'button' gets overwritten in each 'for' loop, and so, even if I click the first button, I get the graph corresponding to the last button.

Comment: The solution to that problem isn't giving it a name, it's in properly creating the button command. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17677649/7432. You can use `lambda j=j: plotMarks(j)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not what you think it is. It can be easily solved by changing:

`command=lambda: plotMarks(j)`
to
`command=lambda j=j: plotMarks(j)`.

The reason this works is because, in your version, you are sticking the variable `j` in all of your commands, and they will all use whatever the final value of `j` is. In the second version you are sticking the **current** value of `j` in your command.

To understand this better all we have to do is expand the `lambdas`.

```
def add2(n):
    return n+2    

#equivalent of your current version    
j = 6
def currentLambdaEquivalent():
    global j
    print(add2(j)) 

currentLambdaEquivalent() #8


#equivalent of second version
def alternateLambdaEquivalent(j):
    print(add2(j))
    
alternateLambdaEquivalent(2) #4
```