# How to update text of buttons created for a list in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Using a for loop to create a list of buttons, and when clicked the button updates it's text to say "unavailable". My code below will only update the latest button, and not the one specified

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

list = ["button 1 available", "button 2 available", "button 3 available"]


def update(item):
    btn["text"] = item.replace("available", "unavailable")


for item in list:
    btn = Button(root, text=item,  command=lambda : update(item))
    btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter assign button command in loop with lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677649/tkinter-assign-button-command-in-loop-with-lambda)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your needs.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

buttonTextList = ["button 1 available", "button 2 available", "button 3 available"]

def update(item, btn):
    btn["text"] = item.replace("available", "unavailable")

# Function to create button
def createButton(item): 
    btn = Button(root, text=item, command=lambda: update(item, btn))
    btn.pack()

# Updated for loop
for item in buttonTextList: 
    createButton(item)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I used Celvin's solution but after a little testing eventually came to conclusion yours would be best in the long run. I'm working on a personal project that has gone from 50 lines of code to about 200. Thank you

Comment: Both the answers use similar approaches, I just did a bit more modifications (or generalizations of the code). Would appreciate it if you upvote the answer by @celvin as well, because he tried (his code works now as well) and he just has 1 rep :) (now 11 after my upvote). although it doesn't matter that much but it gives people the motivation to help others.

Comment: I would upvote everyone who helps whether attempting to answer my question or somebody else's question. But my stackoverflow Reputation is 3 so I get a "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @Sean Oh yeah, I keep forgetting that (I actually didn't check your rep score). You will be there soon :).... Good Luck on your project

Comment: Thanks, I'll go back to upvote all online strangers who helped me... the least I can do ;)

Answer (score 1):

The FOR loop you use will eventually change the 'btn' variable to the button with 'button 3 available' text.
My solution for this is to create another function which creates an individual button:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

list = ["button 1 available", "button 2 available", "button 3 available"]

# Function to change button text
def update(item, btn):
    btn["text"] = item.replace("available", "unavailable")

# Function to create button
def createButton(item): 
    btn = Button(root, text=item, command=lambda: update(item, btn))
    btn.pack()

# Updated for loop
for item in list: 
    createButton(item)
```

Comment: You should have checked your code before posting. How do you expect it to work when update() only takes one positional argument but you are passing it two?

Comment: My bad, that was my mistake

Comment: @Celvin Not a problem, buddy. At least you tried to help someone :).. +10 because your code works now ;)