# Ruby Proc returns the same value for all button clicks in Ruby Tkinter

Tags: ruby, tkinter, event-handling, proc

I'm working on an application with Ruby Tkinter and I've run into an issue defining events for buttons in a loop.

Take for example the code below:

```rb
array = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve"]
new_array = []

for i in 0..(array.length - 1)
    new_array.append [i,Proc.new {puts array[i]}]
end

for i in 0..(new_array.length - 1)
    new_array[i][1].call
end
```

When the code above is run I get the following output as expected:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
eleven
twelve
```

But if I want to create a set of buttons in a loop for my Tkinter application applying the same concept:

```rb
require 'tk'
root = TkRoot.new()
root.title("Test")

list = ["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven","twelve"]

for i in (0..list.length - 1)
    button = Tk::Tile::Button.new(root).pack :side => "top", :expand => false, :fill => "x"
    button.text = (i + 1).to_s
    button.command = Proc.new {puts list[i]}
end

Tk.mainloop
```

I get this output if I press all the buttons in the window from the code above:

```
twelve
twelve
twelve
twelve
twelve
twelve
twelve
twelve
twelve
twelve
twelve
twelve
```

**What is going on? Why are my button events all the same?** I've seen something somewhere about "late event binding" issues for Tk in Python, but I haven't been able to find many solutions. Especially not for Ruby.

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but it's likely the same problem as this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17677649/7432

Comment: `Proc.new { puts list[i] }` is a closure, so *i* never changes.

Comment: @BryanOakley I think so too, but their recommended solution of passing a default parameter doesn't work in Ruby.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Yes. I see the issue now. i is being referred to even as it gets its value changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common closure problem: the procs end up referencing `i` itself rather than its value when `Proc.new` is called. This is more common in JavaScript than Ruby because loops are rarely used in Ruby.

The easiest Ruby solution is to not use a loop at all:

```
list.each_with_index do |item, i|
  button         = Tk::Tile::Button.new(root).pack side: 'top', expand: false, fill: 'x'
  button.text    = (i + 1).to_s
  button.command = Proc.new { puts item }
end
```

You could also say:

```
list.length.times do |i|
  button         = Tk::Tile::Button.new(root).pack side: 'top', expand: false, fill: 'x'
  button.text    = (i + 1).to_s
  button.command = Proc.new { puts list[i] }
end
```

but [`each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) is more idiomatic.