# Python tkinter create multiple variables

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I started to code with tkinter and class methods. I try to code a to-do-list where I can create multiple entries by pressing a button below the entry. And a button next to the entry should change the color of the entry if pressed. The problem now is, that when I create multiple entries, the buttons only change the latest entry. So my question is how do I specify the entry when created?

Sry for obvious mistakes, Im new to coding :p

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import ANCHOR, CENTER, X
from tkinter import messagebox

class App():

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("To-Do-List")
        self.window.geometry("700x700")

        self.x_but, self.y_but = 0.05, 0.2 
        self.x_ent, self.y_ent = 0.05, 0.2
        self.x_but2 = 0.3
        self.check_var = True

        self.start_frame()
        self.grid1()
        self.window.mainloop()
        
    def start_frame(self):
        self.label1 = tk.Label(text="To Do List", font=("", 30))
        self.label1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.05, anchor=CENTER)

    def grid1(self):
        self.button1 = tk.Button(text="Create", command= self.create_field)
        self.button1.place(relx = self.x_but, rely= self.y_but)

    def create_field(self):
        self.y_but += 0.05
        self.button1.place(relx= self.x_but, rely= self.y_but)

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry()
        self.entry1.place(relx= self.x_ent, rely= self.y_ent)
        

        self.button_check = tk.Button(text="✅", height= 1,command=self.check)
        self.button_check.place(relx= self.x_but2, rely=self.y_ent)
       



        self.y_ent += 0.05
    
    def check(self):
        if self.check_var:
            self.entry1.configure(bg="Green")
            self.check_var = False

        else:
            self.entry1.configure(bg="White")
            self.check_var = True

    



app = App()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the `bg` of `self.entry1` which keeps overwriting itself each time an entry is created, so when button is clicked, it is always the last entry. The easiest solution is to define a parameter for `check` and then pass the required entry as an argument to it.

So the method would be:

```
def check(self,ent):
    if self.check_var:
        ent.configure(bg="Green")
        self.check_var = False

    else:
        ent.configure(bg="White")
        self.check_var = True
```

...and your button would be:

```
self.button_check = tk.Button(text="✅", height= 1,command=lambda x=self.entry1: self.check(x))
```

Also I hope you have a good reason to use `place` because using `grid` can make your life much easier, in this case.

For more explanation, read: [Tkinter assign button command in loop with lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677649/tkinter-assign-button-command-in-loop-with-lambda)

Comment: Thanks, but now the variable I defined for the green background doesn't work as planned. So when I check the first entry and check the second, I need 2 clicks to turn it green

Comment: @antal Because each time you click a button the value of _global_ `self.check_var` gets changed. You have to think of a better approach, I think its best to ask a new question for that