# Create a "switched" function for dynamically generated buttons

Tags: python-3.x, function, tkinter, toggle, tkinter-button

I am creating a tool to review metadata with tkinter.  Its users will review the metadata currently associated with a number of datasets and weigh in on whether the metadata is appropriate for the dataset. Each dataset must have its own window. I have a rough layout in place but I am having a difficult time writing functions for the True/False Buttons.

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def a(self,name):
    print(name)

def btn_true(status, i):
    if status == "off":
        true_button.configure(relief=SUNKEN, bg="#D4D5D3")
        false_button.configure(relief=RAISED, bg="#EDEDED")
        status = "on"

def btn_false(status, i):
    if status == "off":
        true_button.configure(relief=RAISED, bg="#EDEDED")
        false_button.configure(relief=SUNKEN, bg="#D4D5D3")
        status = "on"
        


def submit_review():
    print('')

df = pd.DataFrame({'dataset_name': ['people', 'places', 'things'],
                   'tags': ["['proper nouns', 'humans', 'UTF-8', 'NaN', 'â€™', '']", "['proper nouns', 'country', 'geocode', 'alphanumeric']", "['jargon', 'websites', 'unicode']"],
                   'l_desc': ['Lorem ipsum dolor ','sit amet, consectetur ','adipiscing elit, sed '],
                   's_desc': ['Lorem','sit','adipiscing']})

DATASET_ROW = 0

tag_str = df.loc[DATASET_ROW,"tags"]
tag_str =tag_str.replace("'","")
tag_list = tag_str.strip('][').split(', ') 

window = Tk()
window.title("Metadata Evaluation Tool")
window.geometry("700x400")  

## Canvas & Scrollbar
outer_frame = Frame(window)
outer_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
canvas = Canvas(outer_frame)
canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="fred")
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(outer_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command = canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = my_scrollbar.set)
canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="foo")
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all")))

## Place additional frames within the Canvas
metadata_frame = Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=metadata_frame, anchor=NW, )

# Page 
current_dataset =Label(metadata_frame, font='Helvetica 12 bold', text=str(df.loc[DATASET_ROW,"dataset_name"]))
current_dataset.grid(row= 0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky=EW)

# Tags 
tags_info_frame =LabelFrame(metadata_frame, text="Tags",)
tags_info_frame.grid(row= 1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky=EW)
 
for i in range(len(tag_list)):
    iter_tag_label = Label(tags_info_frame, text=tag_list[i])
    iter_tag_label.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky=W,)

    status="on"
    true_button = Button(tags_info_frame,  text="  TRUE  ", relief=SUNKEN, bg="#D4D5D3", command=lambda : btn_true(status=status, i=i))
    true_button.grid(row=i, column=1)

    status="off"
    false_button = Button(tags_info_frame, text=" FALSE ", relief=RAISED, bg="#EDEDED", command=lambda : btn_false(status=status, i=i))
    false_button.grid(row=i, column=2)


for widget in tags_info_frame.winfo_children():
    widget.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=5)

# Descriptions 
desc_info_frame =LabelFrame(metadata_frame, text="Description(s)")
desc_info_frame.grid(row= 2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky=EW)

l_desc_label = Label(desc_info_frame, text="Long Description")
l_desc_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W,)

l_desc_text = Label(desc_info_frame, text=str(df.loc[DATASET_ROW,"l_desc"]), wraplength=500, justify="left")
l_desc_text.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W,)

l_desc_entry = Text(desc_info_frame, height=5, width=20)
l_desc_entry.insert(END, str(df.loc[DATASET_ROW,"l_desc"]))
l_desc_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=EW,)

s_desc_label = Label(desc_info_frame, text="Short Description")
s_desc_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W,)

s_desc_text = Label(desc_info_frame, text=str(df.loc[DATASET_ROW,"s_desc"]), wraplength=500, justify="left")
s_desc_text.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W,)

s_desc_entry = Text(desc_info_frame, height=5, width=20)
s_desc_entry.insert(END, str(df.loc[DATASET_ROW,"s_desc"]))
s_desc_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=EW,)

for widget in desc_info_frame.winfo_children():
    widget.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=5)

# Submit review
confirmation_frame =Frame(metadata_frame)
confirmation_frame.grid(row= 3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky=SE)
button = Button(confirmation_frame, text=" Submit ", command= submit_review)
button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=SE, padx=20, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

**What should happen**
When the window loads, all of the TRUE buttons should be toggled on and all of the FALSE buttons should be toggled off.  Clicking a button that is toggled off should reverse these settings, but only for the buttons in that row.  Clicking a button that is already toggled on should do nothing.

**What does happen**
When the window loads, no button is toggled on or off.  Clicking any of the buttons toggles only the buttons in the last row.

***Updated***

The buttons default to the correct setting but all clicks, regardless of row, only affect the last row of buttons.

Comment: For the first issue, you do not specify the relief of those buttons, so they are all in *raised* relief.  For the second issue, it is the same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677649/tkinter-assign-button-command-in-loop-with-lambda).  I would suggest to use `Radiobutton` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you very much for your help.  I have updated the code block to show the changes I made, but I am still facing difficulty with all actions affecting only the final row of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You have applied the answer in the linked question wrong.

Actually you can use single function instead of two functions:

```py
def btn_toggle(on_button, off_button):
    on_button.configure(relief=SUNKEN, bg="#D4D5D3")
    off_button.configure(relief=RAISED, bg="#EDEDED")

...

for i in range(len(tag_list)):
    iter_tag_label = Label(tags_info_frame, text=tag_list[i])
    iter_tag_label.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky=W,)

    true_button = Button(tags_info_frame,  text="  TRUE  ", relief=SUNKEN, bg="#D4D5D3")
    true_button.grid(row=i, column=1)

    false_button = Button(tags_info_frame, text=" FALSE ", relief=RAISED, bg="#EDEDED")
    false_button.grid(row=i, column=2)

    true_button["command"] = lambda tb=true_button, fb=false_button: btn_toggle(tb, fb)
    false_button["command"] = lambda tb=true_button, fb=false_button: btn_toggle(fb, tb)

...
```