# Why do my functions automatically execute themselves?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, function-call

I have a dict that stores two functions like this:

```
def quick():
    print("dex is 1")

def strong():
    print("str is 1")

def start():
    suffix = {"quick" : quick(), "strong" : strong()}
    suffix.get("quick")

start()
```

And then I execute this code, the output is:

```
dex is 1
str is 1
```

It seems that my `dict.get()` didn't work well here. Why are both of the functions executed, and not just the `quick` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use functions as variables in your dict, and make a call only when needed:

```
def quick():
    print("dex is 1")

def strong():
    print("str is 1")

def start():
# without a `()` after a function's name, the function is just a variable, 
# waiting for a call
    suffix = {"quick" : quick, "strong" : strong}
    suffix.get("quick")() # and here is the actual call to the function

start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Because there are `()` after the function names. Return values of the  function calls are used for dictionary values instead of functions.

```
def start():
    suffix = {"quick" : quick(), "strong" : strong()}
    #                        ^^                   ^^
```

Fix:

```
def start():
    suffix = {"quick" : quick, "strong" : strong} # Use function itself.
    func = suffix.get("quick")  # Get function object.
    func()                      # Call it.
```

Answer (score 2):

when youre writing

```
suffix = {"quick" : quick(), "strong" : strong()}
```

the functions `quick()` and `strong()` are getting executed. You'll need to change that to

```
suffix = {"quick" : quick, "strong" : strong}
```

and call them as:

```
suffix["quick"]()
```

This is a cool feature in python. If you want to pass argumets to your function `quick()`, you can pass them as

```
suffix["quick"](<arguments>)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not storing functions in your dict, but rather the return values of those functions: When you write `quick()`, you're *calling* the function. Your dict ends up looking like this:

```
suffix = {"quick": None, "strong": None}
```

What you want to do is to store the functions themselves in the dict like so:

```
suffix = {"quick": quick, "strong": strong}  # no parentheses!
```

This gives you a dict with two function objects inside. You can now take one of the functions out of the dict and call it:

```
func = suffix.get("quick")
func()
```

And just like that, your code will work correctly.

```
def start():
    suffix = {"quick": quick, "strong": strong}  # no parentheses!
    func = suffix.get("quick")
    func()

start()  # output: dex is 1
```

---

If you need to associate some arguments with the functions in the dict, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277922/python-argument-binders).