# Using a dictionary as a switch statement in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make a simple calculator in Python, using a dictionary. Here's my code:

```
def default():
    print "Incorrect input!"

def add(a, b):
    print a+b

def sub(a, b):
    print a-b

def mult(a, b):
    print a*b

def div(a, b):
    print a/b

line = raw_input("Input: ")
parts = line.split(" ")
part1 = float(parts[0])
op = parts[1];
part3 = float(parts[2])

dict = {
    '+': add(part1, part3),
    '-': sub(part1, part3),
    '*': mult(part1, part3),
    '/': div(part1, part3)
    }

try:
    dict[op]
except KeyError:
    default()
```

but all the functions are activated. What's the problem?

Answer (score 25):

Define your dictionary like pairs of the form `str : function`:

```
my_dict = {'+' : add, 
           '-' : sub, 
           '*' : mult, 
           '/' : div}
```

And then if you want to call an operation, use `my_dict[op]` to get a function, and then pass call it with the corresponding parameters:

```
 my_dict[op] (part1, part3)
|___________|
      |
  function (parameters)
```

**Note:** Don't use Python built-in names as names of variables, or you will hide its implementation. Use `my_dict` instead of `dict` for example.

Comment: note: `dict` is *not* a Python keyword: `'dict' not in keyword.kwlist`. It is a builtin name though: `'dict' in dir(__builtins__)`.

Answer (score 19):

It is because when the dictionary is populated, it executes each operation with the operands, 
and at the end, you're calling `dict[op]` which contains `None` and do nothing with it.

What happens is:

```
# N.B.: in case this is not clear enough, 
#       what follows is the *BAD* code from the OP
#       with inline explainations why this code is wrong

dict = {
    # executes the function add, outputs the result and assign None to the key '+'
    '+': add(part1, part3), 
    # executes the function sub, outputs the result and assign None to the key '-'
    '-': sub(part1, part3),
    # executes the function mult, outputs the result and assign None to the key '*'
    '*': mult(part1, part3),
    # executes the function div, outputs the result and assign None to the key '/'
    '/': div(part1, part3)
    }

try:
    # gets the value at the key "op" and do nothing with it
    dict[op]
except KeyError:
    default()
```

which is why you get all outputs, and nothing happens in your `try` block.

You may want to actually do:

```
dict = {
    '+': add,
    '-': sub,
    '*': mult,
    '/': div
    }

try:
    dict[op](part1, part3)
except KeyError:
    default()
```

but as @christian wisely suggests, you should not use python reserved names as variable names, that could lead you into troubles. And another improvement I advice you todo is to print the result once, and make the functions lambdas:

```
d = {
    '+': lambda x,y: x+y,
    '-': lambda x,y: x-y,
    '*': lambda x,y: x*y,
    '/': lambda x,y: x/y
    }

try:
    print(d[op](part1, part3))
except KeyError:
    default()
```

which will return the result and print it

Comment: N.B.: it's nice to comment on a post when downvoting to indicate what could be wrong, and make suggestions.

Comment: Not a downvoter (because the answer is correct), but I guess you got those `-1` because your solution is almost identical to mine. You just added the `lambda` part.

Comment: well, we actually posted the first part at the same time, so that should'nt be a reason :-)

Comment: I haven't downvoted but my guess is that your answer contains "bad" code without a proper disclaimer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's clearer to use [`get(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) on the dict with the default specified. I prefer to leave *Exceptions* for exceptional circumstances, and it cuts three lines of code and a level of indentation without being obscure.

```py
def calculator(op, part1, part3):
    return {
        '+': part1+part3,
        '-': part1-part3,
        '*': part1*part3,
        '/': part1/part3
    }.get(op, f"The operation '{op}' is not supported!") # for default if op is not found

print(calculator('-', 3, 1))
print(calculator('--', 3, 1))
```

output:

```sh
2
The operation '--' is not supported!
```