# How to use character or string as operator placed in between operands?

Tags: python, string

I want to receive operator (such as '+','-','*','/') and use it directly in the code body.
someting like:

```
char = raw_input('enter your operator:')
a=1
b=5
c=a char b    #error! how can i do it?
```

If the user entered '*', c will be 5.

If the user entered '+', c will be 6 and so on..

Comment: No you can't create your own operators. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932328/python-defining-my-own-operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
import operator

operations = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul, '/': operator.truediv}

char = raw_input('enter your operator:')
a = 1
b = 5
c = operations[char](a, b)

print c
```

**Output** *(for char = +)*

```
6
```

Comment: thanks! that's what I've looked for

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
a=1
b=2
op = '+'
result = eval('{}{}{}'.format(a, op, b)) # result = 3
```

You'll have to translate a and b into strings as well for the `eval` to work.

Comment: `eval` is bad practice

Answer (score 0):

Or Use:

```
from operator import *
char = raw_input('enter your operator:')
a=1
b=5
c={'+':add,'-':sub,'*':mul,'/':truediv}
print(c[char](a,b))
```

Or `int.some operator name`:

```
char = raw_input('enter your operator:')
a=1
b=5
c={'+':int.__add__,'-':int.__sub__,'*':int.__mul__,'/':int.__truediv__}
print(c[char](a,b))
```

Demo Output for both cases:

```
enter your operator:*
5
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be slower than using [operators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) but I am including links that may be helpful and another approach using [lambda](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) that may help understand. Using the `switch dict` approach such as the others have used [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21962789/225020) I'm using `lambda` to coorelate the input into custom methods using this `operators` `dict`:

```
operators = {
    '-': lambda a, b: a-b,
    '+': lambda a, b: a+b,
    '/': lambda a, b: a/b,
    '*': lambda a, b: a/b)
char = raw_input('enter your operator:')
a=1
b=5
c=operations[char](a, b)
print(c)
```