# An alternative to Multiple Combinational Conditions in Python

Tags: memory-management, runtime, big-o, python-3.7

Is there an efficient and faster way in dealing with Multiple Combinational Conditions such as this:

```
if(condition1 and condition2):
    statements
elif((condition1 or condition2) and not condition3):
    statements
elif((condition3 and condition2) and not condition1):
    statements
elif(condition1 or condition2):
    statements
else:
    statements
```

my colleagues said that I should implement a switch case (dict), but I'm not sure how to implement the multiple combined conditions.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: First thing I found when I searched "switch case dict". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962763/using-a-dictionary-as-a-switch-statement-in-python

Comment: As for big-O. The big O of what you have is O(n), where n is the number of conditions. If they are small, then it probably does not matter.

Comment: What is your concern with memory management?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I worry that when checking for multiple conditions it might take a huge chunk of memory,

Comment: I'm trying to optimize my neural network's actions, its actions should depend on certain appropriate conditions.

Comment: Why do you think that (it will take lots of memory)? It only needs to express what is in the code. If you can write it is a few bytes then it is a few bytes. However all conditional code can cause a pipeline stall. I am not sure that this should be a concern in python. If you are processing a list of data, then use filter, map, and maybe reduce. It should run much faster. Then there are libraries such that may do it even faster (they are written in C or Fortran, so are fast).

Comment: The best solution will depend on whether your statement is a procedure (does an action) or a function (calculates and returns a value). It may also depend on other things.

Comment: Thank You for your input! I'll try to implement your solutions. The statement does an action (it doesn't really calculate data). Any recommendations or forums for filtering, and mapping data?

Comment: I'm sorry if I sounded uninformed you mentioned C or Fortran, will it run within python or ?

Comment: Yes some python libraries are written in other languages. You don't have to worry: you can just ignore the implementation. Just install and use.