# How can I write a simple callback function?

Tags: python, callback

I have this example code, trying to demonstrate using a callback function:

```
def callback(a, b):
    print('Sum = {0}'.format(a+b))

def main(callback=None):
    print('Add any two digits.')
    if callback != None:
        callback

main(callback(1, 2))
```

I get this result:

```
Sum = 3
Add any two digits.
```

It seems that the callback function executes before the logic in `main`. Why? How can I make it so that the callback is not called until it is used within `main`?

Comment: [Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51) So, in your case `if callback is not None` would be the right choice.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In this code

```
if callback != None:
    callback
```

`callback` on its own doesn't do anything; it accepts parameters - `def callback(a, b):`

The fact that you did `callback(1, 2)` first will call that function, thereby printing `Sum = 3`, and then `main()` gets called with the result of the `callback` function, which is printing the second line

Since `callback` returns no explicit value, it is returned as `None`.

Thus, your code is equivalent to

```
callback(1, 2)
main()
```

---

### Solution

You could try not calling the function at first and just passing its handle.

```
def callback(n):
    print("Sum = {}".format(n))

def main(a, b, _callback = None):
    print("adding {} + {}".format(a, b))
    if _callback:
        _callback(a+b)

main(1, 2, callback)
```

Comment: Good idea to pass the two args before the call back to make the interpreter do some work for you!

Comment: @erip How do you mean? Like your answer?

Comment: I meant yours is a good idea. :) Forcing the user to pass the arguments before the callback ensures that they exist lest there's a error calling `main`.

Comment: @cricket_007, is it right that callback method is simply passing callable to a function or a class with a purpose to call it later?

Comment: what is meaning of if _callback: ?
_callback would return true when we pass function like main(1, 2, callback) but I dont understand how the if statement evaluates to be true?

Comment: @nad87563 If the function handle has been defined (`is not None`)

Answer (score 11):

Here's what you wanted to do :

```
def callback(a, b):
    print('Sum = {0}'.format(a+b))

def main(a,b,f=None):
    print('Add any two digits.')
    if f is not None:
        f(a,b)

main(1, 2, callback)
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're evaluating the callback before you pass it as a callable. One flexible way to solve the problem would be this:

```
def callback1(a, b):
    print('Sum = {0}'.format(a+b))

def callback2(a):
    print('Square = {0}'.format(a**2))

def callback3():
    print('Hello, world!')

def main(callback=None, cargs=()):
    print('Calling callback.')
    if callback is not None:
        callback(*cargs)

main(callback1, cargs=(1, 2))
main(callback2, cargs=(2,))
main(callback3)
```

Optionally you may want to include a way to support keyword arguments.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, your callback is called whenever it's suffixed with open and close parens; thus it's called when you pass it.

You might want to use a lambda and pass in the values.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def main(callback=None, x=None, y=None):
    print('Add any two digits.')
    if callback != None and x != None and y != None:
        print("Result of callback is {0}".format(callback(x,y)))
    else:
        print("Missing values...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(lambda x, y: x+y, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is executed as follows:

```
main(callback(1, 2))
```

`callback` function is called with `(1, 2)` and it returns `None` (Without return statement, your function prints `Sum = 3` and returns `None`)

`main` function is called with `None` as argument (So `callback != None` will always be `False`)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but perhaps the following may be additional clarification on writing and using a callback function, especially if you wonder where it gets its arguments from and whether you can access its return values (if there is no way to get it from the function that takes the callback function).

The following code defines a class `CallBack` that has two callback methods (functions) `my_callback_sum` and `my_callback_multiply`. The callback methods are fed into the method `foo`.

```
# understanding callback

class CallBack:

    @classmethod
    def my_callback_sum(cls, c_value1, c_value2):
        value = c_value1 + c_value2
        print(f'in my_callback_sum --> {c_value1} + {c_value2} = {value}')
        cls.operator = '+'
        return cls.operator, value

    @classmethod
    def my_callback_multiply(cls, c_value1, c_value2):
        value = c_value1 * c_value2
        print(f'in my_callback_multiply --> {c_value1} * {c_value2} = {value}')
        cls.operator = '*'
        return cls.operator, value

    @staticmethod
    def foo(foo_value, callback):
        _, value = callback(10, foo_value)
        # note foo only returns the value not the operator from callback!
        return value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cb = CallBack()

    value = cb.foo(20, cb.my_callback_sum)
    print(f'in main --> {value} and the operator is {cb.operator}')

    value = cb.foo(20, cb.my_callback_multiply)
    print(f'in main --> {value} and the operator is {cb.operator}')
```

result:

```
in my_callback_sum --> 10 + 20 = 30
in main --> 30 and the operator is +
in my_callback_multiply --> 10 * 20 = 200 
in main --> 200 and the operator is *
```

As you can see one value for the callback function `c_value2` it gets from argument `foo_value` in `foo` and given in `main` the value 20, while `c_value1` it gets internally from `foo` in this case the value 10 (and may be not clearly visible if `foo` is some method of a third party imported module, like pyaudio).

The return value of the callback function functions can be retrieved by adding it to the namespace of the class `CallBack`, in this case `cls.operator`

Comment: This does not appear to be a callback function as it does not "callback" a function defined outside the class.  To me, this is a function by reference...  Great technique for abstraction, but not technically a callback, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous functions

```
def callback(a, b):
    print('Sum = {0}'.format(a+b))

def main(callback=None):
    print('Add any two digits.')
    if callback is not None:
        callback()

tmp_func = lambda: main(lambda: callback(2,3))
tmp_func()

#OR

tmp_func = lambda x,y: main(lambda: callback(x,y))
tmp_func(2,4)
```