# Use arguments of one function as arguments for other function

Tags: python, arguments, keyword, keyword-argument

Suppose I have the following function

```
def f(x,y,**kwargs):
    if 'z' in kwargs:
        z = kwargs['z']
    else:
        z = 0
    print(x + y + z)
```

which takes two arguments and an optional keyword argument. I now want to get a function g that works just as f but for which the value of z is predetermined. Hence, I could do the following

```
def g(x,y):
    z = 3 
    f(x,y, z = 3)
```

But what can I do if I do not know the number of non-keyword arguments that f takes. I can get the list of these arguments by

```
args = inspect.getargspec(f)[0]
```

But, if I now define g as

```
g(args):
    z = 3
    f(args, z=z)
```

this of course does not work as only one mandatory argument is passed to f. How do I get around this? That is, if I have a function that takes keyword arguments, how do I define a second function exactly the same expect that the keyword arguments take predeterminde values?

Comment: if you add a `*` before `args` in `f`, such as `f(*args, z=z)`, it should work?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here:

1. Define `g` with [varargs](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists):

   ```
   def g(*args):
       return f(*args, z=3)
   ```

   Or, if you need keyword arguments as well:

   ```
   def g(*args, **kwargs):
       kwargs['z'] = 3
       return f(*args, **kwargs)
   ```
2. Use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

   ```
   import functools

   g = functools.partial(f, z=3)
   ```

   See also this related question: [Python Argument Binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277922/python-argument-binders).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not quite yet what I was hoping for. In my first example, where the number of arguments were known, the resulting function g had no varargs or keyword arguments.  In your first example however you have varargs and in your second example you have kwargs.

Comment: @lbf_1994 Why do you care whether `g` has varargs or not? If you pass too few or too many arguments, it'll still throw an error as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `functools.partial` to achieve this

```
import functools
f = functools.partial(f, z=2)

# the following example is the usage of partial function f
x = f(1, 2)
y = f(1, 2, k=3)
z = f(1, 2, z=4)
```