# How can I pre-set arguments in JavaScript function call? (Partial Function Application)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am trying to write a JavaScript function that will return its first argument(function) with all the rest of its arguments as preset parameters to that function.

So:

```
function out(a, b) {
    document.write(a + " " + b);
}

function setter(...) {...}

setter(out, "hello")("world");
setter(out, "hello", "world")();
```

Would output "hello world" twice.  for some implementation of setter

I ran into an issue with manipulating the arguments array on my first try, but it seems there would be a better way to do this.

Comment: I recommend the `curry` function of [Lodash](http://lodash.com/docs#curry). BTW I recommend the whole library, it is very useful.

Comment: [bind: partially applied functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#partially_applied_functions)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

First of all, you need a partial - [**there is a difference between a partial and a curry**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218025/what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application) - and here is all you need, *without a framework*:

```
function partial(func /*, 0..n args */) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return function() {
    var allArguments = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    return func.apply(this, allArguments);
  };
}
```

Now, using your example, you can do exactly what you are after:

```
partial(out, "hello")("world");
partial(out, "hello", "world")();

// and here is my own extended example
var sayHelloTo = partial(out, "Hello");
sayHelloTo("World");
sayHelloTo("Alex");
```

The `partial()` function could be used to implement, but *is not* currying. Here is a quote from [**a blog post on the difference**](http://www.uncarved.com/blog/not_currying.mrk):

> Where partial application takes a function and from it builds a function which takes fewer arguments, currying builds functions which take multiple arguments by composition of functions which each take a single argument.

Comment: Could you edit this?  func.apply( this, allArguments) needs to be return func.apply(this, allArguments)

Comment: Done - wasn't really looking beyond your non-returning example function, so I neglected it originally. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting your answer up just because I've searched for something to do this before.

Comment: `Function.prototype.pass = function(){
   var args=arguments, func = this;
   return function(){ func.apply(this,args);}
};`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer You should post that as an answer on this page. I love the simplicity of it.

Answer (score 3):

Is [curried javascript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/index.html) what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't think he needs currying, per se - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218025/what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application

Comment: Link no longer works. Is this the same page? http://www.crockford.com/javascript/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Using Javascript's `apply()`, you can modify the `function prototype`

```
Function.prototype.pass = function() {
    var args = arguments,
        func = this;
    return function() {
        func.apply(this, args);
    }
};
```

You can then call it as `out.pass('hello','world')`

`apply` takes an array for 2nd argument/parameter.

`arguments` is property available inside function which contains all parameters in array like structure.

One other common way to do this is to use `bind`

`loadedFunc = func.bind(this, v1, v2, v3);`

then

`loadedFunc() === this.func(v1,v2,v3);`

this kinda suffice, even though little ugly.

Comment: i think you should add a proper explanation how this works; An example of OP's function should be included too.

Comment: A lot of people are against modifications of base prototypes for trivial purposes, but this one seems ideal, maintaining readability throughout your code.

Comment: personally i think i've just used bind for most cases though, ill add an example of how

Answer (score 2):

If you use Dojo you just call dojo.hitch() that does almost exactly what you want. Almost — because it can be used to pack the context as well. But your example is first:

```
dojo.hitch(out, "hello")("world");
dojo.hitch(out, "hello", "world")();
```

As well as:

```
var A = {
  sep: ", ",
  out: function(a, b){ console.log(a + this.sep + b); }
};

// using functions in context    
dojo.hitch(A, A.out, "hello")("world");
dojo.hitch(A, A.out, "hello", "world")();

// using names in context
dojo.hitch(A, "out", "hello")("world");
dojo.hitch(A, "out", "hello", "world")();
```

dojo.hitch() is the part of the Dojo Base, so as soon as you included dojo.js it is there for you.

Another general facility is available in dojox.lang.functional.curry module (documented in [Functional fun in JavaScript with Dojo](http://lazutkin.com/blog/2008/jan/12/functional-fun-javascript-dojo/) — just look on this page for "curry"). Specifically you may want to look at curry(), and partial().

curry() accumulates arguments (like in your example) but with one difference: as soon as the arity is satisfied it calls the function returning the value. Implementing your example:

```
df.curry(out)("hello")("world");
df.curry(out)("hello", "world");
```

Notice that the last line doesn't have "()" at the end — it is called automatically.

partial() allows to replace arguments at random:

```
df.partial(out, df.arg, "world")("hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for this. It's an ES5 addition.

In addition to the common usecase of setting a function's context (`this` value), it can also set partial arguments.

```js
function out(a, b) {
  document.write(a + " " + b);
}

function setter(func) {
  return func.bind.apply(func, [window].concat([].slice.call(arguments).slice(1)));
}

setter(out, "hello")("world");
setter(out, "hello", "world")();
```

My `setter` function is actually very simple. The longest part is just getting the list of arguments. I'll break up the code like this:

```
func.bind.apply(func, [window].concat([].slice.call(arguments).slice(1)))
func.bind.apply(                                                        )  // need to use apply to pass multiple arguments as an array to bind()
                func,                                                      // apply needs a context to be run in
                      [window].concat(                                 )   // pass an array of arguments to bind(), starting with window, to be the global context
                                      [].slice.call(arguments).slice(1)    // convert the arguments list to an array, and chop off the initial value
```

It's supported in [these browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Function.prototype.bind): Chrome 7+, Firefox 4+, IE9+. MDN (linked at the beginning) has a polyfill though.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to achieve presetting of parameters without calling the function straight away (when e.g. awaiting user confirmation), is to "dress" the function in another anonymous function.

Instead of: `exportFile(docType)`

Do: `function(){ return exportFile(docType) }`

Comment: The only thing I would add to this answer (the simplest compared with all the other ones above) is to add binding at the end, as in function(){return exportFile(docType)}.bind(this) to safely transfer the context to the function inside

Answer (score 0):

**
EDIT: See Jason Bunting's response. This answer actually shows a sub-par way of chaining numerous out calls, not a single out-call with presets for some of the arguments. If this answer actually helps with a similar problem, you should be sure to make use of apply and call as Jason recommends, instead of the obscure way to use eval that I thought up.
**

Well... your out will actually write "undefined" a lot in this... but this should be close to what you want:

```
function out(a, b) {
    document.write(a + " " + b);
}

function getArgString( args, start ) {
    var argStr = "";
    for( var i = start; i < args.length; i++ ) {
        if( argStr != "" ) {
            argStr = argStr + ", ";
        }
        argStr = argStr + "arguments[" + i + "]"
    }
    return argStr;
}

function setter(func) {
    var argStr = getArgString( arguments, 1 );
    eval( "func( " + argStr + ");" );
    var newSettter = function() {
        var argStr = getArgString( arguments, 0 );
        if( argStr == "" ) {
            argStr = "func";
        } else {
            argStr = "func, " + argStr;
        }
        return eval( "setter( " + argStr + ");" );
    }
    return newSettter;
}

setter(out, "hello")("world");
setter(out, "hello", "world")();
```

I'd probably move the code in getArgString into the setter function itself though... a little bit safer since I used 'eval's.

Comment: Right idea, but horrible implementation. See my answer - you do not need to build things up as strings, JavaScript has call() and apply() functions that make things like this easier.

Comment: Huh... never heard of call or apply functions before - those do make it easier.

Comment: I would suggest spending some time reading up on them - while they have a very niche use, they are quite useful for those niche uses!

Answer (score -1):

Using closures is another option. Use functions that return other functions!