# How can I pass a reference to a function, with parameters?

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, anonymous-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pre-set arguments in JavaScript function call? (Partial Function Application)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321113/how-can-i-pre-set-arguments-in-javascript-function-call-partial-function-appli)

I need to able to **pass a reference to a function with a given set of parameters**.

Here is an example of passing a reference ***without*** parameters:

```
var f = function () {
    //Some logic here...
};

var fr = f; //Here I am passing a reference to function 'f', without parameters
fr(); //the 'f' function is invoked, without parameters
```

Now what I need to do is pass the same `f` function, but this time I would need to pass parameters to the reference.  Now, I can do it with an anonymous function and invoke the `f` function with parameters inside the newly created function, like such:

```
var f = function () {
        //Some logic here...
    };

var fr = function (pars) {
    f(pars);
}; //Here I am creating an anonymous function, and invoking f inside it

fr({p : 'a parameter'}); //Invoking the fr function, that will later invoke the f function with parameters
```

But my question is, **Is there a way to pass a direct reference to the `f` function With parameters to `fr`, but without enclosing it in an anonymous function?**

*What do I need to assign to `fr` to make it invokable without parameters (`fr()`), so that f(1,2,3) is executed when `fr` is invoked?*

**[UPDATE]** 
I followed [Jason Bunting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373157/javascript-passing-a-reference-to-a-function-with-parameters#373216)'s answer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321113) about the *Partial Function* and the JavaScript function he posts there is exactly what I was looking for.  Here is the solution:

```
function partial(func /*, 0..n args */) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).splice(1);
  return function() {
    var allArguments = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    return func.apply(this, allArguments);
  };
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I had trouble with the first statement (var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).splice(1);) and had to use this instead:

var args = new Array();
for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    args.push(arguments[i]);
}

Comment: just in case anyone needs this: 

`Function.prototype.pass = function(){
   var args=arguments, func = this;
   return function(){ func.apply(this,args);}
};`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

What you are after is called **partial function application**.

Don't be fooled by those that don't understand the subtle difference between that and currying, they *are* different.

Partial function application can be used to implement, but *is not* currying. Here is a quote from [**a blog post on the difference**](http://www.uncarved.com/blog/not_currying.mrk):

> Where partial application takes a function and from it builds a function which takes fewer arguments, currying builds functions which take multiple arguments by composition of functions which each take a single argument.

This has already been answered, see this question for your answer: [**How can I pre-set arguments in JavaScript function call?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321113)

Example:

```
var fr = partial(f, 1, 2, 3);

// now, when you invoke fr() it will invoke f(1,2,3)
fr();
```

Again, see that question for the details.

Comment: What do I need to assign to `fr` to make it invokable without parameters (`fr()`), so that f(1,2,3) is executed when `fr` is invoked

Comment: Note for future readers, make sure you include the `partial` function provided by Jason in [his other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/321527/1366033)

Comment: As an alternative to Jason's `partial` function, the [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org) library offers a `_.partial` function as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can also overload the Function prototype:

```
// partially applies the specified arguments to a function, returning a new function
Function.prototype.curry = function( ) {
    var func = this;
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
    var appliedArgs = slice.call( arguments, 0 );

    return function( ) {
        var leftoverArgs = slice.call( arguments, 0 );
        return func.apply( this, appliedArgs.concat( leftoverArgs ) );
    };
};

// can do other fancy things:

// flips the first two arguments of a function
Function.prototype.flip = function( ) {
    var func = this;
    return function( ) {
        var first = arguments[0];
        var second = arguments[1];
        var rest = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 2 );
        var newArgs = [second, first].concat( rest );

        return func.apply( this, newArgs );
    };
};

/*
e.g.

var foo = function( a, b, c, d ) { console.log( a, b, c, d ); }
var iAmA = foo.curry( "I", "am", "a" );
iAmA( "Donkey" );
-> I am a Donkey

var bah = foo.flip( );
bah( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
-> 2 1 3 4
*/
```