# What's the best practice for passing a Javascript function with parameters without executing it?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, partial-application

What's the most efficient/the best practice for passing a Javascript function with parameters without executing it, and why? Here is the choice I know :

**Make a anonymous method**

```
jQuery("#target").click(function() {
    onTargetClick("myCoolParam");
});

function onTargetClick(coolParam) {
    // some epic code...
}
```

**Use partial function application**
(See: [Partial function application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373157/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-function-with-parameters))

```
jQuery("#target").click(partial(onTargetClick, "myCoolParam"));

function onTargetClick(coolParam) {
    // some epic code...
}

function partial(func /*, 0..n args */) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).splice(1);
    return function() {
        var allArguments = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        return func.apply(this, allArguments);
    };
}
```

**EDIT for the partial function**

```
function partial(func /*, 0..n args */) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return function() {
        var allArguments = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        return func.apply(this, allArguments);
    };
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use `.bind()`, or a closure

Comment: "Best" questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow, they invite opinion-based answers. There may be an objective way to ask this question, but...

Comment: There's certainly an objective way to answer it.  All of the ways of doing this have advantages and disadvantages, many of which are measurable, such as code length and execution time.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: :-) Many opinion-based questions can be answered objectively. Many aren't. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for the precision. I fix the post, and my own code :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It depends**

Using a wrapper function as in your first example is direct, easy to read, pragmatic, and on modern engines unlikely to have unpleasant side-effects related to being a closure over the context you're using it in (because modern engines optimize trivial closures in many cases). With older engines, that didn't optimize closures, it could have lead to things being kept in memory unnecessarily (and still could, with a more complex closure; but one such as yours which doesn't use `eval`, `new Function`, or `with`, and which references just one variable presumably not declared in the immediately-containing context, is a good candidate for optimization).

Using JavaScript's `Function#bind` avoids the closure issue; is a bit more concise; and is likely, on modern engines, to be extremely efficient (while not being *inefficient* on older engines where it needs to be polyfilled). It does muck up the `this` value, though, which can be a problem in event handlers (although you weren't using `this` in your example).

Using a function like your `partial` or PrototypeJS's `Function#curry` also has the benefits of avoiding the closure issue and being concise, is unlikely to be *in*efficient, and uses the `this` value that was given to the function they generate. They have the downside of not being standard, so you have to provide them and people reading your code have to understand what they do.

Take your choice.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which allows to pass additional parameters:

```
jQuery("#target").click(onTargetClick.bind(null, "myCoolParam"));
```

Comment: So, with `bind`, you have to specify the `this` parameter at binding time?

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: Yes. JavaScript doesn't currently have a built-in curry function that doesn't require the thisArg (which surprised me; when they added `bind`, which PrototypeJS had been adding for years, they chose not to add `curry`, which was also well-represented in prior art).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder *JavaScript doesn't currently have a built-in curry function that doesn't require the thisArg*. Do you imply arrow function from ES6?

Comment: @dfsq: No, lexical `this` binding is a separate topic. I meant something like the OP's `partial` or PrototypeJS's `curry`, which unlike `bind` use the `this` the resulting function called with.