# Use named function to catch errors in promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do this:

```
var error = (reason) => {
        console.log(reason);
    };

//actually other promise
Promise.resolve()
    .catch(error())
    .then(render(req, res));
```

How can I pass the reason to the error function?

Comment: `.catch(error())` ==> `.catch(error)`

Comment: @Tushar was even faster than your question. that's impressive, Tushar :D . Anyway, further reading about referencing a function in js: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373157/how-can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-function-with-parameters

Comment: @Tushar has been waiting for this question to be asked since early 2015..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `catch(error)` instead of `catch(error())`.

The [`catch` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) expects a Function as argument. To actually add the named function itself, just type `error`. If you type `error()`, the method will be executed first. As a result, it will log "undefined" and, as the function does not return anything, is evaluated to "undefined" as well. So what you essentially call is `catch(undefined)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `catch(error)` instead of `catch(error())` to provide the function defined in the `var error`