# Javascript function objects

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I edited the question so it would make more sense.
I have a function that needs a couple arguments - let's call it `fc()`.  I am passing that function as an argument through other functions (lets call them `fa()` and `fb()`).  Each of the functions that `fc()` passes through add an argument to `fc()`.  How do I pass `fc()` to each function without having to pass `fc()`'s arguments separately? Below is how I want it to work.

```
function fa(fc){
   fc.myvar=something
   fb(fc)
}

function fb(fc){
   fc.myothervar=something
   fc()
}

function fc(){
   doessomething with myvar and myothervar
}
```

Below is how I do it now.  As I add arguments, it's getting confusing because I have to add them to preceding function(s) as well.  `fb()` and `fc()` get used elsewhere and I am loosing some flexibility.

```
function fa(fc){
   myvar=something
   fb(fc,myvar)
}

function fb(fc,myvar){
   myothervar=something
   fc(myvar,myothervar)
}

function fc(myvar,myothervar){
   doessomething with myvar and myothervar
}
```

Thanks for your help

---

**Edit 3 - The code**

I updated my code using JimmyP's solution.  I'd be interested in Jason Bunting's non-hack solution.  Remember that each of these functions are also called from other functions and events.

From the HTML page

```
<input type="text" class="right" dynamicSelect="../selectLists/otherchargetype.aspx,null,calcSalesTax"/>
```

Set event handlers when section is loaded

```
function setDynamicSelectElements(oSet) {
    /**************************************************************************************
    * Sets the event handlers for inputs with dynamic selects
    **************************************************************************************/
    if (oSet.dynamicSelect) {
        var ySelectArgs = oSet.dynamicSelect.split(',');
        with (oSet) {
            onkeyup = function() { findListItem(this); };
            onclick = function() { selectList(ySelectArgs[0], ySelectArgs[1], ySelectArgs[2]) }
        }
    }
}
```

`onclick` event builds list

```
function selectList(sListName, sQuery, fnFollowing) {
    /**************************************************************************************
    * Build a dynamic select list and set each of the events for the table elements
    **************************************************************************************/
    if (fnFollowing) {
        fnFollowing = eval(fnFollowing)//sent text function name, eval to a function
        configureSelectList.clickEvent = fnFollowing
    }
    var oDiv = setDiv(sListName, sQuery, 'dynamicSelect', configureSelectList); //create the div in the right place
    var oSelected = event.srcElement;
    if (oSelected.value) findListItem(oSelected)//highlight the selected item
}
```

Create the list

```
function setDiv(sPageName, sQuery, sClassName, fnBeforeAppend) {
    /**************************************************************************************
    * Creates a div and places a page in it.
    **************************************************************************************/
    var oSelected = event.srcElement;
    var sCursor = oSelected.style.cursor; //remember this for later
    var coords = getElementCoords(oSelected);
    var iBorder = makeNumeric(getStyle(oSelected, 'border-width'))
    var oParent = oSelected.parentNode

    if (!oParent.id) oParent.id = sAutoGenIdPrefix + randomNumber()//create an ID
    var oDiv = document.getElementById(oParent.id + sWindowIdSuffix)//see if the div already exists
    if (!oDiv) {//if not create it and set an id we can use to find it later
        oDiv = document.createElement('DIV')
        oDiv.id = oParent.id + sWindowIdSuffix//give the child an id so we can reference it later    
        oSelected.style.cursor = 'wait'//until the thing is loaded
        oDiv.className = sClassName
        oDiv.style.pixelLeft = coords.x + (iBorder * 2)
        oDiv.style.pixelTop = (coords.y + coords.h + (iBorder * 2))
        XmlHttpPage(sPageName, oDiv, sQuery)
        if (fnBeforeAppend) {
            fnBeforeAppend(oDiv)
        }
        oParent.appendChild(oDiv)
        oSelected.style.cursor = ''//until the thing is loaded//once it's loaded, set the cursor back
        oDiv.style.cursor = ''
    }
    return oDiv;
}
```

Position and size the list

```
function configureSelectList(oDiv, fnOnClick) {
    /**************************************************************************************
    * Build a dynamic select list and set each of the events for the table elements
    * Created in one place and moved to another so that sizing based on the cell width can
    * occur without being affected by stylesheet cascades
    **************************************************************************************/
    if(!fnOnClick) fnOnClick=configureSelectList.clickEvent
    if (!oDiv) oDiv = configureSelectList.Container;
    var oTable = getDecendant('TABLE', oDiv)
    document.getElementsByTagName('TABLE')[0].rows[0].cells[0].appendChild(oDiv)//append to the doc so we are style free, then move it later
    if (oTable) {
        for (iRow = 0; iRow < oTable.rows.length; iRow++) {
            var oRow = oTable.rows[iRow]
            oRow.onmouseover = function() { highlightSelection(this) };
            oRow.onmouseout = function() { highlightSelection(this) };
            oRow.style.cursor = 'hand';
            oRow.onclick = function() { closeSelectList(0); fnOnClick ? fnOnClick() : null };
            oRow.cells[0].style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap'
        }
    } else {
        //show some kind of error
    }
    oDiv.style.width = (oTable.offsetWidth + 20) + "px"; //no horiz scroll bars please
    oTable.mouseout = function() { closeSelectList(500) };
    if (oDiv.firstChild.offsetHeight < oDiv.offsetHeight) oDiv.style.height = oDiv.firstChild.offsetHeight//make sure the list is not too big for a few of items
}
```

Comment: ...What exactly are you trying to do/  I'm really confused by this pseudocode.  Does fa() declare/instantiate avar/bvar?

Comment: Your lack of semicolons is alarming -- you should really end each statement with a semicolon or else you are asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so - where to start? :) Here is the partial function to begin with, you will need this (now and in the future, if you spend a lot of time hacking JavaScript):

```
function partial(func /*, 0..n args */) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return function() {
    var allArguments = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    return func.apply(this, allArguments);
  };
}
```

I see a lot of things about your code that make me cringe, but since I don't have time to really critique it, and you didn't ask for it, I will suggest the following if you want to rid yourself of the hack you are currently using, and a few other things:

### The setDynamicSelectElements() function

In this function, you can change this line:

```
onclick = function() { selectList(ySelectArgs[0], ySelectArgs[1], ySelectArgs[2]) }
```

To this:

```
onclick = function() { selectList.apply(null, ySelectArgs); }
```

### The selectList() function

In this function, you can get rid of this code where you are using eval - don't ever use eval unless you have a good reason to do so, it is very risky (go read up on it):

```
if (fnFollowing) {
   fnFollowing = eval(fnFollowing)
   configureSelectList.clickEvent = fnFollowing
}
```

And use this instead:

```
if(fnFollowing) {
   fnFollowing = window[fnFollowing]; //this will find the function in the global scope
}
```

Then, change this line:

```
var oDiv = setDiv(sListName, sQuery, 'dynamicSelect', configureSelectList);
```

To this:

```
var oDiv = setDiv(sListName, sQuery, 'dynamicSelect', partial(configureSelectListAlternate, fnFollowing));
```

Now, in that code I provided, I have "configureSelectListAlternate" - that is a function that is the same as "configureSelectList" but has the parameters in the reverse order - if you can reverse the order of the parameters to "configureSelectList" instead, do that, otherwise here is my version:

```
function configureSelectListAlternate(fnOnClick, oDiv) {
   configureSelectList(oDiv, fnOnClick);
}
```

### The configureSelectList() function

In this function, you can eliminate this line:

```
if(!fnOnClick) fnOnClick=configureSelectList.clickEvent
```

That isn't needed any longer. Now, I see something I don't understand:

```
if (!oDiv) oDiv = configureSelectList.Container;
```

I didn't see you hook that Container property on in any of the other code. Unless you need this line, you should be able to get rid of it.

The setDiv() function can stay the same.

---

Not too exciting, but you get the idea - your code really could use some cleanup - are you avoiding the use of a library like jQuery or [**MochiKit**](http://www.mochikit.com) for a good reason? It would make your life a lot easier...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for such a complete answer. I appreciate it more than you know.  In answer to your last question, I very rarely put anything in my code I don't completely understand or couldn’t write myself. It makes the learning curve steeper, but has proven to be a very valuable philosophy.  I had to improve before I could completely grasp the ramifications of your partial function.  Probably like you, I prefer 'better' to 'easier.' :)

Answer (score 1):

A function's properties are not available as variables in the local scope. You must access them as properties. So, within 'fc' you could access 'myvar' in one of two ways:

```
// #1
arguments.callee.myvar;
// #2
fc.myvar;
```

Either's fine...

Comment: arguments.callee is really expensive in modern js engines :-/

Comment: Expensive isn't the problem, the problems is that this is, at best, a hack - I simply wish the original poster was a bit more clear on what he wanted, or shall I say, able to post the question in a way that was clearer...

Comment: I used your method and it works perfectly.  Before I mark your answer as accepted I am curious about Jason's non-hack solution. Education :)  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [**Partial Function Application**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321113/how-can-i-pre-set-arguments-in-javascript-function-call-partial-function-applic), or possibly currying?

Here is a quote from [**a blog post on the difference**](http://www.uncarved.com/blog/not_currying.mrk):

> Where partial application takes a function and from it builds a function which takes fewer arguments, currying builds functions which take multiple arguments by composition of functions which each take a single argument.

If possible, it would help us help you if you could simplify your example and/or provide actual JS code instead of pseudocode.

Comment: I think this may be what I am looking for, but the examples are a little confusing.  I will do some research and see if it clicks.

Comment: The examples are no more confusing than yours. :) Seriously though, why does the function you call "fc" need to pass through the others to get arguments? Why can't you get those from fb and fa? Seriously though, a *real* example of what you want to do would help, and I mean what you want to do, not what you *think* you need to do (i.e. what you think the code needs to look like, there is more than one way to skin a cat).

Comment: I will post the code. The reason that it has to go through fa and fb is because each function is called in different contexts from different functions or events.  I could combine all of them into fc, but then I would have the exact same logic repeated in fa and fb for other functions.  I am hoping for a more elegant way to skin this cat.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try inheritance - by passing your whatever object as an argument, you gain access to whatever variables inside, like:

```
function Obj (iString) { // Base object
    this.string = iString;
}
var myObj = new Obj ("text");

function InheritedObj (objInstance) { // Object with Obj vars
    this.subObj = objInstance;
}
var myInheritedObj = new InheritedObj (myObj);

var myVar = myInheritedObj.subObj.string;
document.write (myVar);
```

subObj will take the form of myObj, so you can access the variables inside.