# Queueing functions and Ajax in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, queue

I've got two functions and one problem.

```
hideTable();
ajaxCall(params);
```

The function hideTable

```
function hideTable() {
    if (effects) {
        $('#jquerytable tbody').fadeOut(speed);
    }
}
```

I want the ajaxCall function to be executed after the hideTable function (which takes a little time). The showTable function should be executed after the ajax call.
I tried a lot but nothing worked fine for me. The Ajax call starts before the hideTable function is finished. I think I could use the jQuery queue but I don't know how to apply it to this problem.

By the way, I don't want to use a callback function beacause I want to reuse the hideTable function in other contexts.

Would be nice if you could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's animate and hide functions have callbacks you can use.

```
animate( params, [duration], [easing], [callback] )
hide( speed, callback )
```

So what is the code for hideTable? Does it use $().hide() ? If so, set the callback to be your ajax function

Comment: Thats a good answer. However, is there another without a callback?

Comment: That's by far the easiest solution. If you want to reuse the hidetable function, just pass in the callback as a parameter.

Comment: There are many other (less desirable) was to solve the problem. You could have a global variable keep track of the state of the table (hidden, animating, shown). Of course, you'd be using the callback to update the global from animating to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

@nosredna answer to use callbacks is the way to go but if you want do do it with jquery queue
i suggest you to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774077/jquery-synchronous-functions/1774177#1774177) to a similar question