# Add multiple variable passed as parameter to function currying

Tags: javascript, function, currying

How can I achieve these scenarios using function currying?

```
add(3,4)(3)
add(3)(4)(3)
add(3)(4,3)
```

I have read so many blogs not able to find this kind of scenario. can someone help me on this.

Comment: Check Underscore or Ramda library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pre-set arguments in JavaScript function call? (Partial Function Application)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/321113/218196)

Comment: Thanks Felix Kling.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
var total = 0;
function add(){
    // Add up every argument received
    for (var i in arguments)
        total += arguments[i];
        
    return add;
}

add(3,4)(3);
console.log(total);

add(3)(4)(3);
console.log(total);

add(3)(4,3);
console.log(total);
```

## Update

If you do not want the function to depend on global variable, save the value as an attribute of `add` function instead

```js
function add(){
    // Add up every argument received
    for (var i in arguments)
        add.total += arguments[i];
        
    return add;
}

add.total = 0;
add.toString = function(){
  var total = add.total;
  
  add.total = 0;
  
  return total;
};

var sum1 = add(3,4)(3);
alert( sum1 );

var sum2 = add(3)(4)(3);
alert( sum2 );

var sum3 = add(3)(4,3);
alert( sum3 );
```

Comment: Thanks
@Thum Choon Tat for example

Comment: @FelixKling hghi

Answer (score 0):

I see two currying scenarios here:

**1.**

```
add(3,4)(3)
add(3)(4,3)
```

and

**2.**

```
add(3)(4)(3)
```

The first one you can address with:

```
function add() {
    const args1 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function() {
        const args2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        return args1.concat(args2).reduce(function(a, i) { return a + i });
    }
}
```

The second one with:

```
function add() {
    const args1 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function() {
        const args2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        return function() {
            const args3 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            return args1.concat(args2).concat(args3).reduce(function(a, i) { return a + i });
        }
    }
}
```

I did not find a solution to have a function which tackles both at the same time.

Comment: **@gil.fernandes**: yes, you are correct  

**read the articles posted by Felix Kling** . 
Possible duplicate of How can I pre-set arguments in JavaScript function call? (Partial Function Application) – Felix Kling yesterday