# Proper Currying in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, currying

Given a method `DoSomething` that takes a (parameterless) function and handles it in some way. Is there a better way to create the "overloads" for functions with parameters than the snippet below?

```
public static TResult DoSomething<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
{
    //call func() and do something else
}

public static TResult DoSomething<T0, TResult>(
    Func<T0, TResult> func,
    T0 arg0)
{
    return DoSomething(() => func(arg0));
}

public static TResult DoSomething<T0, T1, TResult>(
    Func<T0, T1, TResult> func,
    T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
{
    return DoSomething(arg => func(arg, arg1), arg0);
}

public static TResult DoSomething<T0, T1, T2, TResult>(
    Func<T0, T1, T2, TResult> func,
    T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
{
    return DoSomething(arg => func(arg, arg1, arg2), arg0);
}
```

Comment: Did you check this blog post? [http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/currying-in-c-with-oliver-sturm.html](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/currying-in-c-with-oliver-sturm.html)

Comment: Here are a couple posts that might be interesting if you're trying to curry in C#: http://blogs.msdn.com/wesdyer/archive/2007/01/29/currying-and-partial-function-application.aspx http://diditwith.net/2007/10/23/BuildingFunctionsFromFunctionsPart2FunctionComposition.aspx

Comment: +1 for the wesdyer link - you'll get a really solid understanding of a few lesser understood concepts if you also read the related Fibonacci post:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx

Comment: msdn links are broke.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

EDIT: As noted in comments, this is partial application rather than currying. I wrote a [blog post on my understanding of the difference](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/01/30/currying-vs-partial-function-application/), which folks may find interesting.

Well, it's not particularly different - but I'd separate out the currying part from the "calling DoSomething" part:

```
public static Func<TResult> Apply<TResult, TArg> (Func<TArg, TResult> func, TArg arg)
{
    return () => func(arg);
}

public static Func<TResult> Apply<TResult, TArg1, TArg2> (Func<TArg1, TArg2, TResult> func,
                                                          TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2)
{
    return () => func(arg1, arg2);
}

// etc
```

Then:

```
DoSomething(Apply(foo, 1));
```

That way you can reuse the currying code in other situations - including cases where you don't want to call the newly-returned delegate immediately. (You might want to curry it more later on, for example.)

Comment: Why do you return Func<TResult> instead of Func<TResult, Func<Targ1, Targ2>> ?

Comment: Because Func<TResult> is what you want to be able to pass into DoSomething. The idea is that the Curry method should take a function which takes some parameters, as well as values for those parameters, and return a function which takes fewer parameters (0 in this case).

Comment: I thought the idea was that a Func<TResult, TArg1, Targ2> was should be converted to a function with less parameters Func<TResult, Func<Targ1, TArg2>>. You can create a default dosomething with a lot of parameters and curried variants

Comment: But Func<TResult, Func<TArg1, TArg2>> is a function which *takes* a TResult and returns a Func<TArg1, TArg2>. Yes, you want to reduce the number of parameters - but by supplying the values, not by dealing with functions to convert from one argument type to another.

Comment: But you can use a func like () => "myValue"

Comment: @Paco: Yes, you can if you only want to use it in a single place. If you want to be able to use the resulting function several times, currying it explicitly can be helpful. It's nothing magical - you could use the body of the Curry method anywhere that you called the method - but it's just handy.

Comment: The problem is see with the separate Curry function is that i push the work from me to the user of my code. Where to place the Curry function? There aren't global functions in C#.

Comment: Yes, it's the Math.Sin problem again. Java's static imports are a nice solution to this. I do think it's nicer to have it in one place than duplicating this for each method that it might be applicable for though.

Comment: I'll try if extension methods like
public static Func<T> Curry<T0, T>(this Func<T0, T> func, T0 arg0)
work

Comment: Unfortunately extension methods don't work on lambda expressions: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/01/08/extension-methods-on-lamdba-expressions-don-t-work-unfortunately.aspx

Comment: I agree with Paco. IMO this solution does partial application, not currying. See http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2266

Comment: However, the solution fits the question

Comment: I suspect that both myself and the original questioner are confused as to what currying means. It sounds like a lot of the rest of the world is too. Interesting question: is it too late to rescue the term? Should we give up on it and start with the same definition, but for a new term? Sounds awful..

Comment: I see there's even a question here on SO to disambiguate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218025/what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application

Comment: Cool - that's a much clearer explanation than I've seen elsewhere :)

Comment: in light of the disambiguation question, is the given code Partial Application or currying?

Comment: @Maslow: Partial application, I think. See the blog post I've now referenced.

Comment: public static Func<MAKES, Func<MY, HEAD>> Curry<MAKES, MY, HEAD>(this Func<MAKES, MY, HEAD> spin)
        {
            return makes => my => spin(makes, my);
        }

Answer (score 4):

The @Jon Skeet answer is right, but write by hand all possibles overload is something insane, so you can use a lib like [Curryfy](https://github.com/leandromoh/Curryfy) that do this job for you. Curryfy lib particularly exposes Curry, UnCurry and ApplyPartial extension methods, with a lot of overloads.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the method that allows to write unlimited calls of functions using `dynamic` (like Curry in js):

```cs
dynamic Sum(int a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    return new Func<int, dynamic>(b => Sum(a + b));
}
```

If you call it like this `Sum(2)(3)(4)(10)` the output will be:

```
2
5
9
19
```

Comment: I tried the code above, but inside Linqpad I found it a bit problematic to get the final value from the example. Your code worked a lot better inside Javascript console to get the final value.

A more straightforwards approach here would be to stick with params. 

`void Main()
{
 var nums = new[] { 2, 3, 4, 10};
 Console.WriteLine(nums.Sum());
}
int Sum(params int[] args) => args.Sum();`

Answer (score 0):

Currying is defined as taking multiple arguments into a set of series which accept one argument.

I have created a set of helper methods for currying using lambda operator and chaining them. I have bothered to create helper methods up to four arguments, as we see the helper methods gets more overwhelming the more arguments we get but the pattern of them is the same.

Consider the following extension methods for currying in C#:

```
public static class FunctionExtensions
{
    public static Func<T1, TResult> Curried<T1, TResult>(this Func<T1, TResult> func)
    {
        return x1 => func(x1);
    }
    
    public static Func<T1, Func<T2, TResult>> Curried<T1, T2, TResult>(this Func<T1, T2, TResult> func)
    {
        return x1 => x2 => func(x1, x2);
    }

    public static Func<T1, Func<T2, Func<T3, TResult>>> Curried<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(this Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult> func)
    {
        return x1 => x2 => x3 => func(x1, x2, x3);
    }

    public static Func<T1, Func<T2, Func<T3, Func<T4, TResult>>>> Curried<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>(this Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult> func)
    {
        return x1 => x2 => x3 => x4 => func(x1, x2, x3,x4);
    }
}
```

Here are a set of methods to test out the currying helper extension methods above.

```
int FooFourArgs(string st, float x, int j, int k)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Inside method FooFourArgs. Got parameters: st={st}, x={x}, j={j}, k={k}");
    return 42;
}

int FooThreeArgs(string st, float x, int j)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Inside method FooThreeArgs. Got parameters: st={st}, x={x}, j={j}");
    return 42;
}

int FooTwoArgs(string st, float x)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Inside method FooTwoArgs. Got parameters: st={st}, x={x}");
    return 41;
}

int FooOneArgs(string st)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Inside method FooOneArgs. Got parameters: st={st}");
    return 40;
}
```

The following main method tests the currying of the methods above:

```
void Main()
{
    var curryOneArgsDelegate = new Func<string, int>((st) => FooOneArgs(st)).Curried();
    var curryOneArgsPhaseOne = curryOneArgsDelegate("hello");

    var curryTwoArgsDelegate = new Func<string, float, int>((st, x) => FooTwoArgs(st,x)).Curried();
    var curryTwoArgsPhaseOne = curryTwoArgsDelegate("hello");
    var curryTwoArgsPhaseTwo = curryTwoArgsPhaseOne(3.14f);

    var curryThreeArgsDelegate = new Func<string, float, int, int>((st, x, j) => FooThreeArgs(st, x, j)).Curried();
    var curryThreeArgsPhaseOne = curryThreeArgsDelegate("hello");
    var curryThreeArgsPhaseTwo = curryThreeArgsPhaseOne(3.14f);
    var curryThreeArgsPhaseThree = curryThreeArgsPhaseTwo(123); 
    //Or call currying in a single call passing in two or more parametres
    var curryThreeArgsPhaseOneToThree = curryThreeArgsDelegate("hello")(3.14f)(123);

    var curryFourArgsDelegate = new Func<string, float, int, int, int>((st, x, j, k) => FooFourArgs(st, x, j, k)).Curried();
    var curryFourArgsPhaseOne = curryFourArgsDelegate("hello");
    var curryFourArgsNextPhases = curryFourArgsPhaseOne(3.14f)(123)(456); //just pass in the last arguments if they are known at this stage
    curryFourArgsDelegate("hello")(3.14f)(123)(456); //you can pass in 1-4 parameters to FooFourArgs method - all in a single call for example or one by one
}
```

The methods we defined will be called when ALL parameters are passed in and we can choose if we pass in one argument at a time or pass in multipe arguments one by one at the same time as shown in the main method.

Here is the output we get, I tested the code above inside Linqpad 7:

```
Inside method FooOneArgs. Got parameters: st=hello
Inside method FooTwoArgs. Got parameters: st=hello, x=3,14
Inside method FooThreeArgs. Got parameters: st=hello, x=3,14, j=123
Inside method FooThreeArgs. Got parameters: st=hello, x=3,14, j=123
Inside method FooFourArgs. Got parameters: st=hello, x=3,14, j=123, k=456
```

The extension methods looks a bit cumbersome but I recall having seen some reference source code defined generic methods up to 16 arguments with overloads, which should cover most cases. In this example you at least have the curry overloads for up to four arguments, using chained lambda operators.