# Converting between Func with different # of type args

Tags: c#, generics, currying

Are there built in methods for converting between the various types of Func delegates?  That is, suppose you need a Func, but you have a Func (and you have the value that should be passed in for the T parameter). For example:

```
static TREsult Foo<TResult>(Func<TResult> f)
{
   // ...
   TResult result = f();
   // ...
   return result;
}

static int MyFunc(int i)
{
    return i;
}

void CallFoo()
{
    Func<int> func = ConvertFunc(MyFunc, 1); // Does this family of methods exist?
    int j = Foo(func);
}
```

I've written my own, like this:

```
    static Func<TResult> ConvertFunc<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> f1, T t)
    {
        return () => f1(t);
    }

    static Func<TResult> ConvertFunc<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<T1, T2, TResult> f2, T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        return () => f2(t1, t2);
    }

    // etc.
```

But I'm wondering if a family of methods like this exists (or even if there's a better way to do this).

Essentially, I'm doing this for a case where there is some boiler plate code in a method followed by a function call (where the number and types in the function will vary, but the return type is the same), followed by more boiler plate code.

All opinions welcome! Thanks.

Comment: `() => MyFunc(1)` is more concise (and IMO readable) than `ConvertFunc(MyFunc, 1)`.  So why would you want this family of methods?

Comment: The operation you're looking for is called currying and basically the Lambda you have above is the proposed way to do it in C#

http://csharpfeeds.com/post/11485/Mmm_Curry.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper Currying in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411572/proper-currying-in-c)

Comment: This has been asked before and more than once -- search for "currying". But in one sentence: what you are doing is fine.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'll read up on those threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static Func<TResult> ConvertFunc<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> f1, T t)
{
    return () => f1(t);
}
```

This kind of code to me looks a bit dangerous - not that by itself is anything wrong but *need to be careful*. You are using closure to embed an input variable in the function. But this could lead to difficult bugs since if the variable changes between converting `Func` and running it, the result would be different.

I am just curious what would be the benefit. Are you trying to hide away input parameter from the consumer of the function? As long as the variable is a local one passed to it, would be fine.

**In terms of a solution**, there would not be one since .NET has created 16 different generic `Func<>` exactly for the same reason.

You can perhaps use **reflection** to implement a solution but you would be paying a penalty for calling the functions. `MethodInfo.GetGenericArguments()` would give you the types and you then can use `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod()` to create new ones.

---

### Update

Just to illustrate my point:

```
    static int Double(int number)
    {
        return number * 2;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int i = 2;
        Func<int> f = () => Double(i);
        i = 3;
        Console.WriteLine(f()); // prints 6 and not 4

    }
```

Comment: Since you are currying by calling a method, aren't the bound values fixed in stone since they are parameters, i.e. copies of the method call arguments with local scope? And if yes, doesn't that make "modified closure" impossible?

Comment: @Jon not really, have a look at my example. I have just updated my answer.

Comment: Your example cheats: it does not curry *by calling a method*, as my previous comment states. Do it by calling `ConvertFunc`, and I believe you will see the difference.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. If the variable (passed as parameter) goes out of scope then you do not get a chance to change it so the side effect will not happen. And that is the **only safe way** to create such methods but if you do change the variable, then it is reflected in the closure.

Comment: My point is that when you pass it as a parameter, the parameter is *a copy of* the original value. If you change the original value *after* calling the currying method but before the variable goes out of scope, you will *not* see the change when the curried method executes.