# Calling partially applied functions from C#

Tags: f#, interop, currying

I have a general function that takes a lot of parameters

```ml
f : a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f
```

I want to provide specialized functions that only take the last two parameters, but provide some fixed values for the first three.

```ml
g : d -> e -> f
h : d -> e -> f
```

Their implementation is something like the following

```ml
g = f someA someB someC
h = f someA' someB' someC'
```

This is all great of course, but when it comes to invoking those functions from C# it's a problem because their types don't get "prettified". Instead I get a bunch of nested `FSharpFunc`s.
I can avoid this problem by defining my functions like

```ml
g d e = f someA someB someC d e
h d e = f someA' someB' someC' d e
```

But this seems like a really simple, mechanical transformation so I'm wondering if there's an automated way to get the same result. Perhaps some attribute I can attach to them?

Comment: [This article](http://www.navision-blog.de/blog/2012/01/30/currying-and-uncurrying-in-c-and-f/) seems to contain the answer. Also, [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411572/proper-currying-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, the first and second options of how to write your `g` and `h` are not exactly the same. In the first case, `f` is applied to three arguments and the resulting new function is stored as an object in the value `g`.

Whereas in the second case, the function `f` is called with all 5 arguments every time with the values of `someA`, `someB` and `someC` being passed at the time of calling `g`.

For most cases, this distinction is not really relevant, but it becomes important when you want to cache some parts of your computation.

Long story short: The transformation has a slight semantic difference and therefore cannot really be done automatically. Just add the arguments to the new `g` and `h`.

Comment: I realize that there are valid reasons why it isn't done automatically, but I don't see why we couldn't have an attribute that we could add to the function to explicitly state we want this transformation done.

Comment: Because F# compiler developers don't have infinite capacity?

Comment: Well, you might be able to make an attribute, but what's the point? just adding the arguments is shorter and simple enough.

Comment: @DanielFabian Because adding an attribute is a solution. Adding parameters is a workaround.