# Passing delegate and parameters to be used in the delegate to function

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I have a method that I want to use as a callback. Lets say its the following:

```
public void TestCallback(int a, int b)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(a + b);
}
```

Now let's say that I want to pass this as a parameter to another method that takes a delegate matching `TestCallback`'s signature.

```
public void TestMethodA(Action<int, int> paramFunc)
{
    TestMethodB(paramFunc);
}
```

In turn, let's say `TestMethodA` passes this delegate to another function, which finally invokes it:

```
public void TestMethodB(Action<int, int> paramFunc)
{
    paramFunc.Invoke(5, 10);
}
```

Now what if I wanted to pass another parameter from `TestMethodA` to TestMethodB` which will finally be used as a parameter for the delegate. Would the best approach to do this be like this:

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestMethodA(TestCallback);
}

public void TestMethodA(Action<int, int> paramFunc)
{
    TestMethodB(paramFunc, 10);
}

public void TestMethodB(Action<int, int> paramFunc, int paramForDelegate)
{
    paramFunc.Invoke(5, paramForDelegate);
}
```

Or like this:

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestMethodA(TestCallback);
}

public void TestMethodA(Action<int, int> paramFunc)
{
    TestMethodB((a, b) => paramFunc(a, 10));
}

public void TestMethodB(Action<int, int> paramFunc)
{
    paramFunc.Invoke(5, 20); // 20 here is just a placeholder and will not be passed to the delegate
}
```

Using the first approach, the methods signatures need to carry all the parameters to be used in the delegate. If for example I had more parameters to pass and there were more chained calls, you can imagine how this would become ugly quickly.

Using the second approach keeps the method signatures cleaner, but I think it also makes the code harder to decipher, and I am forced to invoke my delegate with a parameter that will not actually be passed to it.

Is there a better approach to achieving what I described? That is, passing a delegate and also some parameters to be passed to it when invoked?

Comment: Second approach looks weird, but a similar approach called currying is well used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411572/proper-currying-in-c-sharp

Comment: _"better"_ is subjective, which means off-topic and unsuitable for Stack Overflow. See duplicate for existing question that already discusses the basic technique.