# Are there alternate ways to input a parameter into a task besides using lambda functions?

Tags: c#, task

Are there alternate ways to input a parameter(s) into a task besides using lambda functions?

It seems like `Task.Run(DoSomethingElse(myInput));` should work since `Task.Run(DoSomething);` works but clearly it does not.

Using a lambda function only to convert a function with parameters to one without parameters seems odd, like an awkward cast. `Task.Run(() => DoSomethingElse(myInput));`

```
Main()
{
    object myInput = new();

    Task.Run(DoSomething); // Happy Code
    Task.Run(() => DoSomethingElse(myInput)); // Happy Code 
    Task.Run(DoSomethingElse(myInput)); // CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'SystemAction'
}

Task DoSomething()
{
    // Something
}

Task DoSomethingElse(object input)
{
    // Something else
}
```

Comment: Just to check: are you using `Task.Run` because you explicitly want to start the task in another thread?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: *seems odd* -- not for me.

Comment: If you don't like lambda syntax at that point in the code you can use helper functions/libraries that deal with *partial application* - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411572/proper-currying-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for `Task.Run`, you'll notice that every definition takes either a `Func<Task>` or a `Func<Result>` or some combination therein. However, none of these definitions include a mention of parameters. Plus, what you're sending when you call `Task.Run(DoSomethingElse(myInput))` is the result of calling `DoSomethingElse(myInput)` because this represents a call to the method itself rather than sending the method and its arguments as a parameter. In effect, that's what using a Lambda does. If you really don't want to insert a lambda into your code you could try adding a static method like this:

```
public static Task Run<TItem>(f Func<TItem, Task>, i TItem) {
     return Task.Run(() => f(i));
}
```

Comment: Can I go back to bed? It's only 10am but I'm sleepy :D Have a good one.

Comment: Makes sense that I want to send the method, not the result of the method to `Task.Run()`

Comment: this is only a wrapper, right? if the OP doesn't want add a lambda just to pass parameters, why does he like add an extension method for that?

Comment: @LeiYang If, for instance, he has many usages of this pattern and just wants some syntax sugar on top. But there are many potential solutions to this issue

Answer (score 2):

The [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method is basically a shortcut for the [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew) method, with some default parameters. This is explained in this article by Stephen Toub: [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

The `Task.Factory.StartNew` has also an overload with an `object state` parameter. You could use this overload for your own set of `Task.Run`-like shortcuts.
You would need four of those, to cover all cases with-or-without-result and with-or-without-async-delegate:

```
static Task Run(Action<object> action, object state)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, state, default,
        TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
static Task Run(Func<object, Task> action, object state)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, state, default,
        TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
}
static Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<object, TResult> action, object state)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, state, default,
        TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
static Task<TResult> Run<TResult>(Func<object, Task<TResult>> action, object state)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(action, state, default,
        TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
}
```

Usage example:

```
Task task = Run(DoSomethingElse, myInput);
```

The advantage of this approach is that the `myInput` is not [captured in a closure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions), as it does when you use a lambda, so your program allocates less memory in the heap. It's an optimization with minuscule, and in most cases negligible, impact.

Comment: Interesting solution. That definitely is another approach. Thanks for sharing.