# How curry function should really work?

Tags: javascript, currying

I have function that look like this:

```
function curry(fn) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return function() {
        return fn.call(this, args.concat([].slice.call(arguments)));
    };
}
```

I always thought that's how the function should look like and should work as:

```
function add(a, b, c, d) {
   return a+b+c+d;
}


curry(add, 1, 2)(3, 4);
```

but [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) says that

> it can be called as a chain of functions, each with a single argument

so the curry should look like this:

```
function curry(fn) {
    var args = [];
    return function curring() {
        args = args.concat([].slice.call(arguments));
        if (args.length >= fn.length) {
            return fn.apply(this, args);
        } else {
            return curring;
        }
    };
}
```

and be used as this:

```
function add(a, b, c, d) {
   return a+b+c+d;
}

curry(add)(1)(2)(3)(4);
```

Am I right?

Comment: i think both of them are correct. but according to John Resig in "secret of the javascript ninja" the first method is correct.

Comment: @AhmadF how come? The first one return one function and then result and the second keep returning function until the list or arguments is the same as the number of function parameters.

Comment: I guess that `function add(a, b, c, d)` must return `a+b+c+d` and not `a+b+c+c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, ***currying*** converts a function with many arguments into a series of functions each with one single argument, as in your second `curry` function:

- If you call all of them (in chain), you get the full application of the function, which produces the same result as the original function:
  `curry(add)(1)(2)(3)(4)` returns the same as `add(1, 2, 3, 4)`, i.e.`10`
- If you call only a subset, you get a partially applied function:

  1. `addOne = curry(add)(1);`
  2. `addOneAndTwo = addOne(2);`
  3. `addOneAndTwo(3)(4)` returns `10`

In Javascript, *currying* is usually used as a synonym for partial application, as in your first `curry` function. Paraphrasing [Prototype documentation](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Function/prototype/curry/index.html):

> **curry** curries (burns in) arguments to a function, returning a new function that when called with call the original passing in the curried arguments (along with any new ones).

For more detailed explanations, see [What is the difference between currying and partial application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218025/859646).

Here is a working implementation of a [true curry function in javascript](https://github.com/eborden/js-curry) by *Evan Borden*.

**A few caveats:**

- In your first function, `fn.call` is wrong. You must use `fn.apply`, as the array that you pass as the second argument must be used as a list of arguments and `call` treats it as only one argument.
- Your second function generates a curried function that can be called only 1 time, as each called `curring` instance modify the captured `args` array, which was initialized when `curry` was called.

  For example:

  1. `addOne = curry(add)(1);` defines `addOne` with its own `args` initialized to `[1]`
  2. `addOne(2)(3)(4)` returns `10` and modify `args` to `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
  3. `addOne(2)(3)(4)` (a second time) fails with `addOne(...) is not a function`,
     as `addOne(2)` tries to call `add(1, 2, 3, 4, 2)`

Comment: The first issue is just a typo it should by apply, but the second is error, thanks for pointing it out.