# javascript partial function, arguments

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand partial functions. I found this example (http://blog.thesoftwarecraft.com/2013/05/partial-functions-in-javascript.html) and I am unable to understand completely.

```
function partial(f) {
    console.log(f) // tip(p,check)
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); //0.2

    var test_args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    console.warn(test_args) // [tip(p,check), 0.2]

    return function () {
        console.warn(arguments) //[120, 0, [120, 90, 180]] [90, 0, [120, 90, 180]] ...
        //where do these arguments come from? why don't appear at test_args?

        var other_args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); //[120, 0, [120, 90, 180]] [90, 0, [120, 90, 180]] ...

        console.log(args.concat(other_args)) // added percentage to array[0.2, 120, 0, [120, 90, 180]]

        return f.apply(null, args.concat(other_args)); //we execute tip with all the arguments (only 2 first will be used)
    }
}

function tip(percentage, check) {
    return check * percentage
}

[120, 90, 180].map(partial(tip, 0.2)); //[24, 18, 36]
```

Comment: Based on your question, you need to read up on [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), not partial functions. (And double-check the values you wrote down in the comments, `[90, 0, [120` should be `[90, 1, [120`.)

Comment: [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments), [partial application](http://benalman.com/news/2012/09/partial-application-in-javascript/#partial-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> return function () {
>      console.warn(arguments) //[120, 0, [120, 90, 180]] [90, 0, [120, 90, 180]] ...
> ```
>
> where do these arguments come from? why don't appear at test_args?

Because it's a new function - the returned one - which has a new `arguments` object. You can check here:

```
var tipper = partial(tip,0.2);
[120, 90, 180].map(function(el) {
     console.log(arguments); // here they are!
     return tipper(el);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In programming languages theory this is known as **partial application**. It basically takes your function that requires *n* arguments and *n-k* arguments and returns a function that has *k* arguments by partially applying these provided *n-k* arguments.

Take this example in a pseudo code

```
function mul(x, y)
    return x*y

function mul2(y)
    return function (x) mul(x, y)

mul(2, 3); // 6
var f = mul2(4); // returns a function
f(5); // 20
```

Although the function takes 2 arguments (*n*), you can make another function out of it by applying only 1 argument (*n-k*). The new function will then require only one argument (*k*).

Your `partial` takes a function and its `arguments`. It stores these arguments in the `args` variable. Then it returns the inner function that itself takes its arguments but since it has to combine the *n-k* arguments from the top level function with *k* arguments of the inner function, you have `concat` and the full list is passed to the original function.

Edit: as Andreas points in the comment, this is not called **currying**. The rest of the answer still holds though.

Comment: [What is the difference between currying and partial application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218025/what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application)