# Create function by making argument of another function constant (clojure,newbie)

Tags: clojure

I just started to learn clojure and I don't have much functional programming experience. Let's say I have a function :

```
(defn process-seq
   [process]
   ...doing something...)
```

that takes another function as an argument. This argument should be a function that takes single argument - a sequence. For example :

```
(defn filter-odd
  [sequence]
  (filter odd? sequence))
```

So I can now write :

```
(process-seq filter-odd)
```

What I don't like about it is that I had to define filter-odd function. I would like to achieve it without defining it. All I want is to pass filter function with constant predicate : odd?.Something like (just a pseudo code that I made up) :

```
(process-seq filter(odd?))
```

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass an anonymous function as parameter:

```
(process-seq (fn [sequence] (filter odd? sequence)))
```

Or even shorter:

```
(process-seq #(filter odd? %))
```

Or as mentioned by [A.Webb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1756702) in the comments, we could use `partial`:

```
(process-seq (partial filter odd?))
```

Comment: Also `(process-seq (partial filter odd?))`

Comment: Partial is not currying.

Comment: @Aralo looks like currying to me, what's the difference? it's even mentioned in the comments of the [documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/partial)

Comment: `partial` is partial application. Currying would be more like `(filter f)` implicitly "noticing" that too few arguments are passed, and returning a new function that expects a collection.

Comment: Currying would be `(def curried-filter (fn [pred] (fn [coll] (filter pred coll))))`. And in this case, `(partial filter odd?)` would correspond to `(curried-filter odd?)`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218025/what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application