# How to differentiate between closure and currying in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have going through some of the documents on function currying and all docs reflects 'closure' by means of 'currying'. so, i doubt how can differentiate between closure and currying?

Have already gone through here and it does not have any marked answer [Does curry function in javascript uses principle of closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912097/does-curry-function-in-javascript-uses-principle-of-closure)

this below code

```
var greet = function(greeting, name) {
  console.log(greeting + ", " + name);
};
greet("Hello", "world"); //"Hello, world"
```

rewritten as (currying) (But, i understand this below code is 'closure')

```
var greetCurried = function(greeting) {
  return function(name) {
    console.log(greeting + ", " + name);
  };
};
```

here is the results that i got:

```
var greetHello = greetCurried("Hello");
greetHello("World!"); //"Hello, World!"
greetHello("Universe!"); //"Hello, Universe!"
```

the above code represents the 'closure'. if so, how can i differentiate between closure and currying please?

How to differentiate differentiate between closure and currying in javascript

Comment: @Danial A. White  I already read that, but, it does not hold any valuable answer.. this is why i put this question here.. Could you please give your comments why this is duplicate?

Comment: `greetCurried` is curried because it returns another function to take more arguments. `greetHello` is a closure because it closes over `greeting`.