# What is the different between curry and partial function in Ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

It seems the [curry](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#curry) and [partial](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#partial) functions do the exact same thing. (Maybe the only difference is the number of arguments)

Is it just matter of convinience or there is a good reason on having two functions that do kind of similar thing.

Comment: This is almost the same question as [What is the difference between currying and partial application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218025/2907849) only without ramda reference.

Comment: @lonelyelk: ... but because Ramda's `curry` is somewhat non-standard, this might need its own answer.  I'll try my own below.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As you briefly mentioned, `curry` function can take a function with n arguments and return n functions with one argument. Currying is an essential tool to compose functions into higher order functions.

Partial applications of functions is a type of currying. In fact, if you look into Ramda [source code](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/src/internal/_createPartialApplicator.js) you'll see that the `partial` function was implemented using curry function.

```
var _arity = require('./_arity');
var _curry2 = require('./_curry2');


module.exports = function _createPartialApplicator(concat) {
  return _curry2(function(fn, args) {
    return _arity(Math.max(0, fn.length - args.length), function() {
      return fn.apply(this, concat(args, arguments));
    });
  });
};
```

Also, take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218055/7283346) that explain the different fundamentally.

Comment: This in incorrect: "Partial applications of functions is a type of currying." Currying is the *transformation of a function* of a type such as `(a, b, c) -> d` into a function of type `a -> b -> c -> d`.

Answer (score 10):

A lot of answers from the wider FP community might steer you a little wrong.  Ramda's currying seems to me to carry the spirit of currying from ML-style languages into Javascript, but is not strictly the same.

Partial application is probably fairly standard in Ramda.  (Disclaimer: I'm one of the Ramda authors.)  It's also much easier to describe.  Ramda's `partial` function accepts a function of `n` arguments and a list of `k` arguments (for some `0 < k < n`), and returns a new function of `n - k` arguments that will call the original function with your new arguments and the original ones:

```
const f = (a, b, c, d, e) => a + b + c + d + e;
// f :: a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> a + b + c + d + e

const g = partial(f, [1, 2]);
g.length; //=> 3
g(3, 4, 5); //=> 15
g(3); //=> NaN ≍ 1 + 2 + 3 + undefined + undefined)
// g :: (c, d, e) -> 1 + 2 + c + d + e
```

The function returned is just a simple function of the remaining parameters.  If you call it with too few, it will act as though you called the original function with too few as well.

Currying is a slightly different story.  In [many languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218055/7283346), a `curry` function would convert a function of `n` parameters into a nested sequence of 1-parameter function, so that `(a, b, c) => f(a, b, c)` transforms into `a => (b => (c => f(a, b, c))`, which can be written without confusion as `a => b => c => f(a, b, c)`.  In Ramda, we are a little more flexible, allowing you to supply as many of the arguments as you choose at a single call, each time returning a function until you have supplied enough total parameters to satisfy the original function, at which point we call it and return that value.  It's probably easier to explain with examples:

```
const f = (a, b, c, d, e) => a + b + c + d + e;
// f :: a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> a + b + c + d + e

const h5 = curry(f);
h5.length; //=> 5

const h3 = h5(1, 2);
h3.length; //=> 3
h3(3, 4, 5); //=> 15

const h2a = h3(3);
h2a.length; //=> 2
h2a(4, 5); //=> 15

const h2b = h5(1, 2, 3);
h2b.length; //=> 2
h2b(4, 5); //=> 15

const h2c = h5(1)(2, 3);
h2c.length; //=> 2
h2c(4, 5); //=> 15

const h2d = h5(1)(2)(3);
h2d.length; //=> 2
h2d(4, 5); //=> 15

const h1a = h3(3, 4);
h1a.length; //=> 1
h1a(5); //=> 15

const h1b = h2a(4);
h1b.length; //=> 1
h1b(5); //=> 15

// h5 :: (a, b, c, d, e) -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: (a, b, c, d) -> e -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: (a, b, c) -> (d, e) -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: (a, b, c) -> d -> e -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: (a, b) -> (c, d, e) -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: (a, b) -> (c, d) -> e -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: (a, b) -> c -> (d, e) -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: (a, b) -> c -> d -> e -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: a -> (b, c, d, e) -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: a -> (b, c, d) -> e -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: a -> (b, c) -> (d, e) -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: a -> (b, c) -> d -> e -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: a -> b -> (c, d, e) -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: a -> b -> (c, d) -> e -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: a -> b -> c -> (d, e) -> a + b + c + d + e
//    :: a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> a + b + c + d + e
```

Because `curry` is so much more flexible, I rarely use `partial` myself.  But there are people who are, ahem, *partial* to it.