# Convert into Java 8 function

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

How can I write the following function using Java 8?

```
private static final Function<String, Integer> EmpIdToInt = (id) -> {   
    return Integer.valueOf(ACI.generate("emp",id).revealId().intValue());
};
```

Is there a better way of writing this function in Java 8?

Can anyone help?

Comment: You're using 8, what's the issue?

Comment: Is there a better way of writing this function in java 8??

Comment: `Integer.valueOf()` is unnecessary.

Comment: `Function<String,Integer> empIdToInt=id->ACI.generate("emp",id).revealId().intValue();`

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a better way of writing this function in java 8??

you're already using the features of java 8 and yes you can make the code shorter by removing 
 `(` `)` because there is only one param and removing `{` `}` because there is only one statement of execution.

you could simplify it like so:

```
private static final Function<String, Integer> EmpIdToInt = id -> Integer.valueOf(ACI.generate("emp",id).revealId().intValue());
```

Answer (score 2):

*Note*: I take away `private static final`  for printing page.

**IF** your `revealId` is an Integer you can simplified to :

```
Function<String, Integer> EmpIdToInt = id -> ACI.generate("emp",id).revealId();
```

**OR** when `revealId` is not an Integer, but  a `int` will be auto-boxing to an `Integer`, so you can remove the `Integer.valueOf` method call:

```
Function<String, Integer> EmpIdToInt = id -> ACI.generate("emp",id)
                                                .revealId().intValue();
```

**OR** you can using a `curry` method chaining the functions step by step:

*Note*: class `X` is where `revealId` method is declared, and class `Y` is where `intValue` method is declared.

```
// revealId is an Integer
Function<String, Integer> EmpIdToInt = curry(ACI::generate, "emp")
                                      .andThen(X::revealId);
// revealId is not an Integer
Function<String, Integer> EmpIdToInt = curry(ACI::generate, "emp")
                                      .andThen(X::revealId)
                                      .andThen(Y::intValue);

private static <T, A, R> Function<T, R> curry(BiFunction<A, T, R> it, A arg) {
    return other -> it.apply(arg, other);
}
```

Comment: I think it's safe to assume `Y` is a `Number`.

Comment: @shmosel maybe we are right, but I left it to the OP for thinking.

Comment: To be a little pedantic, I think you're demonstrating partial application rather than currying.

Comment: @shmosel My mind is to convey the **reusable** and **describility** by using `curry` method to chaining the functions. as you see the `curry(ACI::generate, "emp")
                                      .andThen(X::revealId)` can be reused.

Comment: I understand what you're doing, and I like it. I'm just saying currying isn't the accurate term for it.

Comment: I believe it's "partial application". See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218025/what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application) for more detail.

Comment: @shmosel is correct. Simply said, currying means converting the `(a,t)->r` function to the `a->t->r` form. When you apply that (outer) function to a value, you get a function result of the `t -> r` form, which is partial application. However, I usually call such methods `bind`, as the concept of binding parameter argument values to a function, to get a function with less parameters, is immediately understandable for average Java developers without the need to know the FP terms.

Comment: @shmosel I found  it's "partial application" if you starts at `Function<String, Integer>`, and it's "currying" when you starts at `ACI::generate` after reading the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218025/what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application), am I right?

Comment: No, currying would be `private static <T, A, R> Function<T, Function<A, R>> curry(BiFunction<A, T, R> it) { return t -> a -> it.apply(a, t); }` As said in my previous comment, when you do `curry(ACI::generate).apply("emp")`, you’re doing partial function application, which your method does in one step.

Comment: @Holger yes, you are right, but I want to remove the middle function since java8 have not provided `curry` method in Functional Interface. but I think `bind` method is not better than `curry`. Can you give me some advice, Holger?

Comment: @holi-java: well, in our projects, we also have a need to bind other parameters than the first, e.g. `Function<T,R> bindSecond(BiFunction<T,A,R> func, A arg)`, which have no FP equivalent, so there is no benefit in naming `bindFirst` as `partialApplication` or `curryAndApply`, just because it happens to match that FP concept. Consistency is more important. Note that in real FP languages, you usually don’t have functions of such names, as currying or partial application happens implicitly. The need for specialized methods translating from one interface to another, is a Java specific issue.