# In currying why does the outside, initiating function appear to be the innermost function?

Tags: javascript, currying

In the simple, 2 layer `currying` example below the word dog is passed into the y argument.

```js
"use strict";

function layer2(x) {
    return function(y) {
        return console.log(x, y);
    }
}

var layer1 = layer2('cat');

layer1('dog');
```

I know it works this way and I can reliably reproduce this.  However I can't understand the mechanics of why this works.  If I made a 100 layer example layer 1 would be the innermost function and the pattern would work outwards from that point.  What piece of basic mechanics causes this?  Thanks so much for any input!

Comment: I read the post twice but still don't know what is the question. Can you please be a bit more specific

Comment: It utilizes the concept of closure in javascript for currying the function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, lexical scoping is what makes this possible. See, `layer2` function in your example returns another function that has two variables in its scope:

```
y - its own argument
x - parameter passed into `layer2` function
```

The key point here is that once you store that returned function, `x` value is set and will never change. Again, in terms of your example, function stored in `layer1` variable - result of `layer2('cat')` - has `x` name bound to 'cat' string value.

Comment: Please chose to close instead of answering. Since you know the solution, you are more likely to find proper dupe.

Comment: I considered this to be a different question - not 'what closures are', but rather 'what makes currying possible'. And my closing vote will be binding (close this question immediately), hence no action. I upvoted your comment however, as understanding how closure works is crucial to understanding how currying works in JS.

Comment: The two answers to this question have helped me immensely!  I understand the concept of closure and can see how it applies to this.  But until these answers I was not picking up on that at all.  Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, your example shows not currying, but partial application; those are similar, but [a bit different beasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218025/what-is-the-difference-between-currying-and-partial-application).

Comment: Considering the fact that curring functions rely on closure scope, understanding them will explain you how currying works. Hence marked it as dupe. But its just my POV. Have a good day. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. When you call `layer2('cat')` it will return the function:

```
function(y) {
  return console.log(x, y);
}
```

Now, `layer1('dog')` returns function call `return console.log(x,y);` on which x is received already in a call `layer2('cat')`, and y is being called from `function(y)`.

Here's a very good read blog https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/understanding-javascript-closures/ which will help you further.

Comment: Please chose to close instead of answering. Since you know the solution, you are more likely to find better dupe.

Comment: That makes perfect sense!  Now I can see how the returns are stepping backwards.  Thanks so much!  I'll read the link now.