# How does the following functions return statement work

Tags: javascript

```
function greaterThan(n) {
  return m => m > n;
}
```

I'm struggling to understand how this return statement works and what the 'm' variable actually does.

Comment: It is a fat arrow syntax and the function returns an anonymous function to check if the m is greater.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I will post on example of it.

Comment: this is [currying](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/) but since arrow syntax is used you may as well write it simpler: `const greaterThan = n => m => m > n;`

Comment: You can always [check it](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwE4FMCGV2oCoAWmYAFGAJSIDeAUIohlCKkgLaIC8AfIuz2AG4aAXxpA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=).

Answer (score 4):

`greaterThan` is the function which takes a parameter `n` and returns a function which takes parameter `m`. The returned function compares `m` and `n` and returns `boolean` value.

for Ex:

```
greaterThan(5)(4); // Returns false
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `greaterThan` accepts a parameter `n` and returns a new function which accepts the parameter `m` which in turn returns `true` if the argument passed as `m` is greater than `n`;

Same method in ES5 code:

```js
function greaterThan(n) {
  return function(m) {
    return m > n
  }
}

var greaterThan5 = greaterThan(5); // This returns a function

// Call that function with a parameter to check if that is greater than 5

console.log(greaterThan5(10)); //true [n=5, m=10]
console.log(greaterThan5(1)); //false [n=5, m=1]

//Note: The newly created function will have `n` "fixed" as `5` because of how JS closures work
```

Handy Reference:

[Javascript Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

[Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

[JS Functions (and how they are first class objects in JS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

Answer (score 1):

That is a fat arrow syntax. The snippet follows a closure feature of javascript, where you store one value and you pass another value in it to process.

```js
function greaterThan(n) {
  return m => m > n;
}

console.log(greaterThan(5)(10));
console.log(greaterThan(5)(1));
```

Comment: You should also mention about currying.\

Comment: I had also posted [about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47936084/2138752) but I was just confused. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you see here is known as [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

> Currying is the technique of translating the evaluation of a function that takes multiple arguments (or a tuple of arguments) into evaluating a sequence of functions, each with a single argument.

Currying is mainly a part of the functional paradigm. It is used mainly to construct functions that you can reuse later.

You can read more about currying in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying). As others have already mentioned, the `greaterThan` method returns a function which you can call in turn after you call greater than. The returned function returns a boolean based on the values you pass to it.

> What the variable m actually does?

The function you have provided can be rewritten as:

```
function greaterThan(n) {
  return function greaterThanN(m) {
     return m > n;
  }
}
```

So m is an argument to the function that is being returned. This function forms a closure on n and checks if m is greater than m and returns that value.